# What does a type followed by _t (underscore-t) represent?

Tags: c, naming-conventions, types

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find it with the Stack Overflow search or Google. What does a type followed by a `_t` mean? Such as

```
int_t anInt;
```

I see it a lot in C code meant to deal closely with hardware—I can't help but think that they're related.

Comment: Where is `int_t` defined? If it's always defined as `int`, it's not useful; it's much clearer to use `int` directly. If it's not always defined as `int` (say, if it could be `long int` or `short int`), then it's a poorly chosen and confusing name.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

As Douglas Mayle noted, it basically denotes a type name.   Consequently, you would be ill-advised to end variable or function names with '`_t`' since it could cause some confusion.  As well as `size_t`, the C89 standard defines `wchar_t`, `off_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, and probably some others I've forgotten.  The C99 standard defines a lot of extra types, such as `uintptr_t`, `intmax_t`, `int8_t`, `uint_least16_t`, `uint_fast32_t`, and so on.  These new types are formally defined in `<stdint.h>` but most often you will use `<inttypes.h>` which (unusually for standard C headers) includes `<stdint.h>`.  It (`<inttypes.h>`) also defines macros for use with the `printf()` and `scanf()`.

As Matt Curtis noted, there is no significance to the compiler in the suffix; it is a human-oriented convention.

However, you should also note that [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) defines a lot of extra type names ending in '`_t`', and **reserves the suffix** for the implementation.  That means that if you are working on POSIX-related systems, defining your own type names with the convention is ill-advised.  The system I work on has done it (for more than 20 years); we regularly get tripped up by systems defining types with the same name as we define.

Comment: it seems reasonable that OS and common runtime libraries define types with genericish names; but shouldn't your company's types also be prepended with a prefix or something?

Comment: Yes, they should.  Unfortunately, I wasn't in charge of the naming convention at the time when it was used.  And global search and replace isn't something that's sanctioned - though it could be used to fix a lot of problems, even in a monstrous code base.

Comment: I use _type instead of _t on my typedefs precisely to avoid that.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- What naming convention would you use for user-defined types?

Comment: @Andrew: if you have a convenient abbreviation to use as a prefix, then you may be safe to use `abbr_xxxxx_t` type names.  Without such a prefix, you may get caught any time. Generally, the standardized `_t` types use all lower-case (`FILE` and `DIR` are two exceptions, twice - all caps, and no `_t`), so you could use `CamelCase_t` with moderate safety, with or without the leading caps. The system I mainly work on tends to live dangerously and use `_t` anyway, but it has bitten us on occasions. I tend to use `CamelCase` without a suffix for my own work; my functions are usually all lower-case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I've started using that convention, CamelCase for types, lower_case for functions. I searched this question hoping I wasn't the only one. Thanks for the validation!

Comment: @AustinMullins that's PascalCase, not camelCase. For reference: snake_case, kebab-case, SHOUT_CASE, Title Case, Sentence case

Comment: No version of the C standard up to (and including) C11 have any mention of `off_t`, it is a POSIX extension

Comment: Convention-wise, after running into this problem due to redefining `timer_t` over top of the POSIX definition accidentally, I'm switching from this convention: `typedef struct timer_s { /* definition here */ } timer_t;` and `typedef enum timer_error_e { /* definition here */ } timer_error_t` to this, respectively: `typedef struct Timer_s { /* definition here */ } Timer;` and `typedef enum Timer_error_e { /* definition here */ } Timer_error`. This gets rid of all of my `_t` endings, which are reserved by POSIX.

Answer (score 72):

The `_t` usually wraps an opaque type definition.

GCC merely add names that end with `_t` to the reserved namespace you may not use, to avoid conflicts with future versions of Standard C and POSIX [(GNU C library manual)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html). After some research, I finally found the correct reference inside the POSIX Standard 1003.1: [B.2.12 Data Types](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_12) (Volume: [Rationale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xrat.html), Appendix: [B. Rationale for System Interfaces](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap01.html), Chapter: [B.2 General Information](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html)):

> **B.2.12 Data Types**
> *Defined Types*
> The requirement that additional types defined in this section end in "_t" was prompted by the problem of name space pollution. It is difficult to define a type (where that type is not one defined by POSIX.1-2017) in one header file and use it in another without adding symbols to the name space of the program. To allow implementors to provide their own types, all conforming applications are required to avoid symbols ending in "_t", which permits the implementor to provide additional types. Because a major use of types is in the definition of structure members, which can (and in many cases must) be added to the structures defined in POSIX.1-2017, the need for additional types is compelling.

In a nutshell, the Standard says that there are good chances of extending the Standard types' list, therefore the Standard restricts the `_t` namespace for its own use.

For instance, your program matches *POSIX 1003.1 Issue 7* and you defined a type `foo_t`. *POSIX 1003.1 Issue 8* is eventually released with a newly defined type `foo_t`. Your program does not match the new version, which might be a problem. Restricting the `_t` usage prevents from refactoring the code. Thus, if you aim to a POSIX compliancy, you should definitely avoid the `_t` as the Standard states it.

*Side note: personally, I try to stick to POSIX because I think it gives good basics for clean programming. Moreover, I am pretty fond of [Linux Coding Style (chapter 5)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst#L343) guidelines. There are some good reasons why not using typedef. Hope this help!*

Answer (score 64):

It's a convention used for naming data types, e.g with `typedef`:

```
typedef struct {
  char* model;
  int year;
...
} car_t;
```

Comment: Do not use the `_t` suffix for your own types, since they are reserved in some standards, better use `_T`. Also, never `typedef` an anonymous `struct`, forward declaring this `struct` will become impossible. Give the `struct` a name or do not use `typedef` at all.

Comment: To add to what 12431... (the guy above me) said, you should in general NEVER `typedef` pointers and structs/unions. Doing so is confusing and only serves to obfuscate type information. `struct foo f;` and `union userinput *ui_ptr;` are much clearer and easier to understand than `foo f;` and `userinput ui;`. I know it's tempting to have a short type name, but don't. Function pointers are the one exception where IMO it's okay, e.g. `typedef void (*foobarfn)(struct foobar *);` ... `foobarfn my_callback = find_response(some_input);`

Comment: @BradenBest it's always been crazy to me just how many books, guides, and blogs by "experts" always recommend you do typedef structs, union, pointers, etc. For opaque types: yes; for everything else: no!

Answer (score 19):

It is a standard naming convention for data types, usually defined by typedefs.  A lot of C code that deals with hardware registers uses C99-defined standard names for signed and unsigned fixed-size data types.  As a convention, these names are in a standard header file (stdint.h), and end with _t.

Answer (score 16):

The `_t` does not inherently have any special meaning.  But it has fallen into common use to add the `_t` suffix to typedef's.

You may be more familiar with common C practices for variable naming... This is similar to how it's common to stick a p at the front for a pointer, and to use an underscore in front of global variables (this is a bit less common), and to use the variable names `i`, `j`, and `k` for temporary loop variables.

In code where word-size and ordering is important, it's very common to use custom defined types  that are explicit, such as `BYTE` `WORD` (normally 16-bit) `DWORD` (32-bits).

`int_t` is not so good, because the definition of `int` varies between platforms -- so whose `int` are you conforming to?  (Although, these days, most PC-centric development treats it as 32 bits, much stuff for non-PC development still treat int's as 16 bits).

Comment: To me, this is the best answer provided. Great, simple, and to the point explanation. Thank you @Toybuilder.

Answer (score 13):

It means type.  `size_t` is the size type.

Answer (score 13):

It's just a convention which means "type". It means nothing special to the compiler.

Answer (score 10):

There were a few good explanations about the subject.  Just to add another reason for re-defining the types:

In many embedded projects, all types are redefined to correctly state the given sizing to the types and to improve portability across different platforms (i.e hardware types compilers).

Another reason will be to make your code portable across different OSs and to avoid collisions with existing types in the OS that you are integrating in your code.  For this, usually a unique (as possible) prefix is added.

Example:

```
typedef unsigned long dc_uint32_t;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're dealing with hardware interface code, the author of the code you're looking at might have defined `int_t` to be a specific size integer. The C standard doesn't assign a specific size to the `int` type (it depends on your compiler and target platform, potentially), and using a specific `int_t` type would avoid that portability problem.

This is a particularly important consideration for hardware interface code, which may be why you've first noticed the convention there.

Comment: this will be not very good practice, i would expect one to define [u]int_[32 16 8]_t to make clear what is the size you defining.

Comment: You're quite right, "int_t" by itself tells the programmer that it's a user defined type but not what it really is!

Answer (score 4):

For example in C99, /usr/include/stdint.h:

```
typedef unsigned char           uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short int      uint16_t;
#ifndef __uint32_t_defined
typedef unsigned int            uint32_t;
# define __uint32_t_defined
#endif
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef unsigned long int       uint64_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t;
#endif
```

`_t` always means defined by typedef.

Answer (score 1):

`_t` means "type". It's a common convention to use it with `typedef`s.

I've been using it for years, for instance, in professional code bases, like this: notice my usage of `timer_t` and `timer_error_t`:

```c
typedef struct timer_s 
{ 
    // When the timer was started
    uint32_t start_ticks;
    // How long until the timer expires
    uint32_t timeout_ticks;
    // Whether or not the timer has previously expired without being restarted
    bool expired;
} timer_t;

typedef enum timer_error_e
{
    // No error
    TIMER_ERROR_NONE = 0,
    // You passed in a NULL pointer
    TIMER_ERROR_NULL_POINTER,
    // The timeout value invalid (ex: too large)
    TIMER_ERROR_INVALID_TIMEOUT,
} timer_error_t;
```

However, I recently learned from [@Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/4561887) that POSIX reserves the `_t` suffix for its own types, and I ran into the problem where `timer_t` is already defined by POSIX, preventing the above from compiling!

G++ compile-time error:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/timer_t.h:7:19: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef void* timer_t’
    7 | typedef __timer_t timer_t;
      |                   ^~~~~~~
```

So, I'm switching to this new convention to avoid using the `_t` suffix which is reserved by POSIX. I've made the following changes, thereby removing my usage of `_t`:

```
timer_s --> Timer_s
timer_t --> Timer

timer_error_e --> Timer_error_e
timer_error_t --> Timer_error
```

Here's the final result:

##### Recommended naming convention for structs and enums to avoid redefining `_t` types which are reserved by POSIX

```c
typedef struct Timer_s 
{ 
    // When the timer was started
    uint32_t start_ticks;
    // How long until the timer expires
    uint32_t timeout_ticks;
    // Whether or not the timer has previously expired without being restarted
    bool expired;
} Timer;

typedef enum Timer_error_e
{
    // No error
    TIMER_ERROR_NONE = 0,
    // You passed in a NULL pointer
    TIMER_ERROR_NULL_POINTER,
    // The timeout value invalid (ex: too large)
    TIMER_ERROR_INVALID_TIMEOUT,
} Timer_error;
```

This new convention avoids the risk of having overlapping usages of `_t`.