# What does the "t" in dispatch_queue_t stand for?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I can't seem to find out what the "t" in dispatch_queue_t stands for from Apple's GCD documentation.

At first I thought it was "thread" but after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent) I think it means typedef. If that is the case, what is dispatch_queue_t a typedef of?

Comment: t = type ... check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391447/what-does-the-postfix-t-stand-for-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stands for "type". If the docs don't specify what `dispatch_queue_t` is a `typedef` for, then it's an opaque type: you're not supposed to know, because it's an implementation detail (not part of the API spec).

Comment: ah ok, not knowing small details like what a letter stands for really eats at me, but as long as I know I'm not supposed to know I feel better.  no such thing as a silly question right :)

Comment: @Karuna-bdc, there's a reason for not knowing what's in a `dispatch_queue_t`: new versions of the library you're using might change its implementation. If your software is decoupled from the `dispatch_queue_t` definition, it won't break when that happens.

Comment: the _t for type has been around in the C programming language for as long as I've known/worked with C. It's a pretty common thing. If you look in the low level socket headers, or even stdio.h, you'll see these custom types with a _t all over the place.

Comment: That's answer. However, according to the name of the types and methods, they are really not good APIs