# Typedef struct vs struct? |Definition difference|

Tags: c, struct, typedef, definition

*The following blocks are outside of* `main()` *and before every function (global scope)*

1st block:

```
struct flight {
    int number;
    int capacity;
    int passengers;
};
```

With this you can create array,pointer,variable in contrast with writing `} var;` (which defines only one variable of this custom data type (struct **flight**))

2nd block:

```
typedef struct flight {
    int number;
    int capacity;
    int passengers;
} flight;
```

Declaring this creates a data type **flight** without having to write **struct flight** all the time

My question is why typedef needs flight to be written a second time at the end of a block? 
which is a bit confusing (it looks like only a variable of that datatype)

Comment: Consider: `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;` — the type name introduced is `uint8_t` and the base type it aliases is `unsigned char`.  Now consider: `typedef struct flight flight;` — the type name introduced is `flight` and the derived type it aliases is `struct flight`.  If `struct flight` had not been mentioned before, this also introduces the type `struct flight` as an opaque structure type. You could subsequently define the type with `struct flight { ... };`. C++ does without the need for the typedef of a structure type, but original C did not have that facility and it has never been added.

Comment: There is no global scope in C, I think you meant *file scope*.

Comment: @ouah: There's nothing *called* global scope in C, but it's not a horribly bad name for what the standard calls file scope. (Yes, calling it "file scope" is better.)

Comment: @KeithThompson it's not only a terminology issue: if "global variables" or "global scope" existed, I would expect that an object declared in this scope would be visible in the scope of all translation units.

Comment: To me the more clear way is to write `typedef struct Foo Foo;` then afterwards use your first version. The user can decide whether he wants to write `struct Foo` or just `Foo` when referring to this struct. Some people like to write something slightly different like `typedef struct Foo_ Foo` and then call the struct `struct Foo_` but I personally find that way to be ugly. The struct tag and the typedef are two different things, there's no need to give them different names.

Comment: @Brandin for me the solution (as most as possible) is to follow the Linux kernel style for this particular point and to not use `typedef` for structure types.

Comment: @Jonathan  **If struct flight had not been mentioned before, this also introduces the type struct flight as an opaque structure type. You could subsequently define the type with struct flight** { ... }; Then what is the use of using typedef if we end up using **struct flight** again to define the other objects of this struct type ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja: In my comment, I am postulating that `typedef struct flight flight;` exists somewhere.  This identifies that there is a type `struct flight` (which is incomplete; at this stage, the compiler knows nothing about its size or members), and creates an alias for that type called `flight`.  You can now write functions which take a `flight *` or return a `struct flight *`, without needing any further information.  However, some code, somewhere, is going to manipulate the data fields in the type.  For that code, at least, you need `struct flight { …member definitions… };` somewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My question is why typedef needs flight to be written a second time at the end of a block?

When you declare:

```
typedef struct flight{
    int number;
    int capacity;
    int passengers;
 }flight;
```

you actually declare two things:

- a new structure type `struct flight`
- a type alias name `flight` for `struct flight`.

The reason why the type alias name with `typedef`  appears at the end of the declaration like for any ordinary declaration is because for historical reasons `typedef` was put in the same specifiers category as storage-class specifiers (like `static` or `auto`).

Note that you can just declare:

```
typedef struct {
    int number;
    int capacity;
    int passengers;
}flight;
```

without the tag name if you intend to only use the type identifier `flight`.

Comment: +1. You said 'if you intend to only use'; you could have said 'and you will only be able to use' — there is no `struct flight` available in the tagless version (unless it is some unrelated structure type, which would be poor coding style, but is far from impossible).

Comment: Without the tag name, the type `flight` cannot have members of type `flight*` (because the identifier `flight` isn't visible early enough).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that a lot of software often uses the notation: `typedef struct flight { ... } flight_t`, or sometimes `typedef struct flight_s { ... } flight_t`.

Comment: @Dogbert but on POSIX systems `*_t` names are reserved by the implementation if any header used by POSIX is included.

Comment: @ouah Can you elaborate more on this, or post a link? I've done a fair bit of embedded development (mainly driver dev), and haven't encountered anything that precludes the use of this convention.

Comment: @Dogbert see         https://books.google.com/books?id=rHyMRyDEG3gC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=POSIX+systems+_t&source=bl&ots=vJqmeqNQ7J&sig=SJahDD_AREAqGRzHFCnqkMYhyAg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBWoVChMIvcCo_OLlyAIVAXU-Ch2TQAvz#v=onepage&q=POSIX%20systems%20_t&f=false      and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391447/what-does-the-postfix-t-stand-for-in-c