# Can somebody help me decipher the syntax in these typedef-ing lines?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty rusty with my c++. This is at the beginning of the class declarations in the header file for a bag class which uses an array to store data items. It's supposed to function as, you guessed it, a bag. I get the first line, but after that I don't quite understand what's going on. This seems fairly common so I think there's enough information here to get help.

```
class bag
{
public:
    // TYPEDEFS and MEMBER CONSTANTS
    typedef int value_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    static const size_type DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 30;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of typedef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566027/what-is-the-use-of-typedef)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of another post but not that. Those second two statements are confusing. I didn't see any help with them.

Comment: How come you understand the first typedef, but not the second one?  It's the same thing!  Or do you get confused by the `std::` namespace specifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef int value_type;
```

This line defines that the type bag contains another type called "value_type" that is the same as an int.

```
typedef std::size_t size_type;
```

This line defines that the type bag contains another type called "size_type" that is the same as an std::size_t.

```
static const size_type DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 30;
```

This line defines a constant of type "size_type" (look at the line above to check what it is) that is called DEFAULT_CAPACITY with the value of 30.

That's basic C++ and I don't really know how to explain it better than to spell out the syntax.

Comment: One might add that the `typedef int value_type` has *probably* been done to have a type for the items the bag can hold, so if you suddenly want your bags to hold doubles, you can change that line to `typedef double value_type` instead of searching your source code for `int` variables and decide for each of them whether or not they should be changed to doubles as well. Of course, a more generic way to achieve this is templating.

Comment: Ok then I suppose the big question is what is "an std::size_t"?

Comment: @Beezly It's part of the standard library, an implementation defined unsigned int type.

Comment: @nvoigt It all makes sense now, thanks. I was actually looking up size_t right as you commented. I don't think this a duplicate post, but, well, what should I do? delete it?

Comment: @Beezly, if it's a duplicate, it will be closed as duplicate. It's still somewhat useful as people who are looking things up might hit your question first and if it's closed as duplicate they will be guided to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

The trick I've found with typedefs is to first ignore the `typedef` keyword and look at the other bits; so

```
int value_type;
```

would declare a variable called `value_type` of type `int`. Add the `typedef` keyword, and it's exactly the same, but rather than declaring a new *variable*, you're declaring a new *type* that's an `int`.

I find this helpful in more complex cases like

```
typedef int (*Func)(float, double);
```

Remove `typedef` and you're declaring a function called `*Func` which takes two parameters and returns an int. Add the keyword back in, and you're declaring a function *type* with that signature.

**EDIT:**

From comments on other answers, it seems like it's not so much the typedef itself but `std::size_t` that's giving you bother.

`std::size_t` is itself the name of a standard library type, specifically, the type of the number returned by the built-in `sizeof` operator. It's always an unsigned integer, but the exact type depends on the compiler and the system you're using (and even particular compiler options).

How do you know that `std::size_t` is a type name, rather than a variable name? The short answer is that you often can't, you just have to judge by the name and the context (in fact, sometimes even the compiler doesn't even know whether a name refers to a type or whether it refers to a variable, so you have to tell it). In this case, the fact that it ends in `_t` is a good clue that it's a type (plus the fact it's used in a typedef!).

The `std` part refers to the `std` *namespace*. Namespaces are a C++ facility (also present in other languages, though not C) for avoiding name clashes. You can declare your own, and `std` is a special on reserved for the standard library.

The `A::B` thing is called the *scope resolution operator*, and it tells the compiler "look inside `A` for something named `B`", where `A` can be either class or a namespace.

Comment: +1 for the effort and the very nice tip to ignore the "typedef" keyword at first!

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax of a `typedef` is:

```
"typedef" <name of type> <name of alias for type>
```

The name of the alias is a single identifier. Everything between the `typedef` key word and that last identifier needs to be the name of a/the type for which you're creating an alias. Of course, for things like pointers and references, especially something like an alias for a `pointer to a function returning int and taking a string and a long as parameters`, the name of the alias is going to be buried somewhere in the middle of the declaration, just like it would be when/if you were declaring a variable of that type (in fact, syntactically, `typedef` was originally added to C as a "storage class" like `auto` or `register`, so it occupies exactly the same spot in a declaration as one of them would).

So, in `typedef int value_type` it's creating `value_type` as an alias for `int`.

Note, however, that in this case the `value_type` is nested inside of `bag` so the complete name of the name is `bag::value_type`. If you use other containers, you'll probably have a `value_type` for each. For example:

```
std::vector<unsigned> x;
```

In this case, the `value_type` will also being `unsigned`. `value_type` becomes more interesting with associative containers like `std::map`. For example, given a map like:

```
std::map<std::string, int> foo;
```

...the `value_type` will be `std::pair<const std::string, int>`.

These nested identifiers like `value_type` are used especially heavily in template code that might take containers of different types (or iterators to the contents of such containers), so the `value_type` for a particular container isn't known when the code is written. For example, if you wanted to add together all the items in a container, you could use the container's `value_type` for the type of the result, so when you add together a `vector<int>`, the result would be an `int`, but if you add together a `list<string>`, the result would be a `string`.