# What is the advantage of creating node using typedef?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am always confused what is why we are using **typedef struct node** for creating node rather same thing can be easily implemented using **struct node** only...

Comment: Kindly refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566027/what-is-the-use-of-typedef

Comment: It's a C thing. Both work in C++.

Comment: This construct has some value in C, but very little in C++. Feel free to just write `struct node { ... };`

Comment: Thanks for reference and answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way it is done.

it is usually

```
struct node { ... };
```

versus

```
typedef struct { ... } node; 
//here node is a alias for an anonymous struct or...
typedef struct node_ { ... } node; //note the two names are different
```

In C++ that doesn't make any particular difference: `node` is in any case a type.

But it is different in C, where *node* is a *tag* for the type `struct node` (not just  *node*) in the first case, and just the type `node` in the second case

Libraries defining types that have to work the same for both C and C++ usually adopt the second form, so that they can in any other expression to mention just `node`, instead of `struct node`, like in

```
node* first() { ... }
```

instead of

```
struct node* first() { ... }
```