# why typedef is used so widely in nginx?

Tags: c, nginx, typedef

For example there are so many `typedef`s to a huge number of structures in `ngx_core.h`

```
typedef struct ngx_module_s      ngx_module_t;
typedef struct ngx_conf_s        ngx_conf_t;
typedef struct ngx_cycle_s       ngx_cycle_t;
typedef struct ngx_pool_s        ngx_pool_t;
typedef struct ngx_chain_s       ngx_chain_t;
typedef struct ngx_log_s         ngx_log_t;
typedef struct ngx_array_s       ngx_array_t;
typedef struct ngx_open_file_s   ngx_open_file_t;
typedef struct ngx_command_s     ngx_command_t;
typedef struct ngx_file_s        ngx_file_t;
typedef struct ngx_event_s       ngx_event_t;
typedef struct ngx_event_aio_s   ngx_event_aio_t;
typedef struct ngx_connection_s  ngx_connection_t;
```

In fact, I know the structure name such as `ngx_module_s` is ok to be used, why `typedef` it with `ngx_module_t`? Is this good design? And, what are the benefits to do this?

Is this kind of good practice when programming in the C language? And, what is the name of this practice? Why is it good or bad?

Comment: You don't have use the struct keyword each time you create a variable.

Comment: You might want to give [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3225386/315052) a read.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common practice. You don't have use the struct keyword each time you declare a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Look at one of them, is defined as:

```
struct ngx_command_s {
  ngx_str_t             name;
  ngx_uint_t            type;
  char               *(*set)(ngx_conf_t *cf, ngx_command_t *cmd, void *conf);
  ngx_uint_t            conf;
  ngx_uint_t            offset;
  void                 *post;
 };
```

You can use `ngx_command_s` as follows:

```
struct ngx_command_s *x;
x = malloc(sizeof(struct ngx_command_s));
```

But when you `typedef`, you can avoid the `struct` keyword :

```
typedef struct ngx_command_s ngx_command_t;

ngx_command_t *x;
x = malloc(sizeof(ngx_command_t));
```

> Why is it good or bad?

Some people thinks that `typedef` for structs are unneccessary and confusing, [take a look](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware1/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=10506).

Answer (score 0):

In C, unlike C++, you cannot refer to the `struct` tag directly by name, the `struct` must always accompany it. This is the motivation to using the `typedef`, which is sometimes referred to as type aliasing.

A benefit is that source code can be more clear since redundant information is not cluttering the code. A detriment is that the alias hides the kind of type it is (`struct`, `union`, `enum`, or some other type).

Note that the `_t` suffix on type names is reserved by POSIX, so technically, this violates the POSIX standard.