# C++ type suffix _t, _type or none

Tags: c++, stl, coding-style

C++ sometimes uses the suffix `_type` on type definitions (e.g. `std::vector<T>::value_type`),
also sometimes `_t` (e.g. `std::size_t`), or no suffix (normal classes, and also typedefs like `std::string` which is really `std::basic_string<...>`)

Are there any good conventions on when to use which name?

Comment: It seems `_type` is more common in template meta-programming (for template class member typedefs), whereas no suffix is used when it is not important for the outside whether the typename is a class or a typedef.

For (template) class member types there just seem to be some edge cases when it isn't clear which would be more appropriate.

Comment: in C++14 `_t` suffix is commonly used to indicate an alias template for nested `::type` typedef, e.g. `X_t<T>` stands for `typename X<T>::type`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @MarcoA.'s answer correctly points out, the suffix `_t` is largely inherited from C (and in the global namespace - reserved for POSIX).

This leaves us with "no suffix" and `_type`.

Notice that there is no namespace-scope name in `std` ending in `_type`<sup>*</sup>; all such names are members of classes and class templates (or, in the case of regex-related types, of a nested namespace which largely plays a role of a class). I think that's the distinction: types themselves don't use the `_type` suffix.

The suffix `_type` is only used on members which denote types, and moreover, usually when they denote a type somewhat "external" to the containing class. Compare `std::vector<T>::value_type` and `std::vector<T>::size_type`, which come from the vector's template parameters `T` and `Allocator`, respectively, against `std::vector<T>::iterator`, which is "intrinsic" to the vector class template.

---

* Not entirely true, there are a few such names (also pointed out in a comment by @jrok): `common_type`, `underlying_type`, `is_literal_type`, `true_type`, `false_type`. In the first three, `_type` is not really a suffix, it's an actual part of the name (e.g. a *metafunction* to give the common *type* or the underlying *type*). With `true_type` and `false_type`, it is indeed a suffix (since `true` and `false` are reserved words). I would say it's a *type* which represents a true/false value in the type-based metaprogramming sense.

Comment: `common_type`,`underlying_type`,`is_literal_type`,`true_type`,`false_type`. HA! :)

Comment: There are also cases of a class having both `value` and `value_type` members.

Comment: @jrok: of those, only `true_type` and `false_type` are types with a suffix (metafunction that gives you the type common to two types: `common_type`; had it a suffix it would become `common_type_type` or `common_type_t`). For the rest the `_type` is part of the semantical name, not a suffix. In the case of `true_type` and `false_type`, a suffix needed to be added as `true` and `false` are keywords.

Comment: @jrok I actually remembered `common_type` when posting the answer, but I felt that it's a different case and would just bloat the answer. Nevertheless, you're right that to be 100% correct, it should be addressed. Did so.

Answer (score 6):

As a C heritage the `_t` (that used to mean "*defined via* `typedef`") syntax has been inherited (they're also [SUS/POSIX-reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225396/1938163) in the global namespace).

Types added in C++ and not present in the original C language (e.g. `size_type`) don't need to be shortened.

Keep in mind that to the best of my knowledge this is more of an observation on an established convention rather than a general rule.

Answer (score 3):

Member types are called `type` or `something_type` in the C++ standard library. This is readable and descriptive, and the added verbosity is not usually a problem because users don't normally spell out those type names: most of them are used in function signatures, then `auto` takes care of member function return types, and in C++14 the `_t` type aliases take care of type trait static type members.

That leads to the second point: Free-standing, non-member types are usually called `something_t`: `size_t`, `int64_t`, `decay_t`, etc. There is certainly an element of heritage from C in there, but the convention is maintained in the continuing evolution of C++. Presumably, succinctness is still a useful quality here, since those types are expected to be spelled out in general.

Finally, all the above only applies to what I might call "generic type derivation": Given `X`, give me some related type `X::value_type`, or given an integer, give me the 64-bit variant. The convention is thus restricted to common, vocabulary-type names. The class names of your actual business logic (including `std::string`) presumably do not warrant such a naming pattern, and I don't think many people would like to have to mangle *every* type name.

If you will, the `_t` and `_type` naming conventions apply primarily to the standard library and to certain aspects of the standard library style, but you do not need to take them as some kind of general mandate.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is only relevant for type names **within namespaces** (that aren't `std`).

#### Use no suffix usually, and `_type` for enums

So, here's the thing: the identifier `foo_type` can be interpreted as

- "the identifier of the type for things which are `foo`'s" (e.g. `size_type overall_size = v1.size() + v2.size();`)
- "the identifier of the type for things which are kinds, or types, of foo" (e.g. `employment_type my_employment_type = FIXED_TERM;`)

When you have typedef'ed enums in play, I think you would tend towards the second interpretation - otherwise, what would you call your enum types?

The common aversion to using no suffix is that seeing the identifier `foo` is confusing: Is it a variable, a specific foo? Or is it the type for foos? ... luckily, that's not an issue when you're in a namespace: `my_ns::foo` is obviously a type - you can't get it wrong (assuming you don't use global variables...); so no need for a prefix there.

PS - I employ the practice of suffixing my typedef's within classes with `_type` (`pointer_type`, `value_type`, `reference_type` etc.) I know that contradicts my advice above, but I somehow feel bad breaking with tradition on this point.

Now, you could ask - what happens if you have enums within classes? Well, I try to avoid those, and place my enum inside the surrounding namespace.