# C/C++ underscore t/type (_t/_type) and class names?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I understand that underscore t (`_t`) is used to identify types, as is underscore type (`_type`), often in `typedef` statements.

1. Is there a slightly different usage (e.g. underscore type for templates but underscore t for non-templates)?
2. Why are they not used in declarations? E.g:

   ```
   class person_t { };
   enum error_t { };
   ```

This is different from a previous question on underscore t because it also asks for the difference between underscore type. Also, it's (blindingly) obvious that both suffixes are just convention, but it's not obvious why they are both used in the C++standard. E.g., std::size_t vs std::istream::pos_type.

Comment: It is just a convention, there are style guides which are not using `_t` suffix at all, e.g.: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Type_Names

Comment: There are no rules that correspond to your imagined understanding. It's all arbitrary.

Comment: Please notice that POSIX claims the `…_t` "namespace". Everyone calls their structs `my_type_t`, but actually you are not supposed to.

Comment: Did you read the edit above explaining the difference between this and the existing question ?

Comment: Voting to reopen - how is this opinion based? "Which is better?" would be an opinion-based question, but this is not asking that.

Comment: @Kay that's why I use _T instead. I'm under the impression that _T isn't claimed by POSIX or any other standard for its own libraries. Is that true?

Comment: As @Kay observed, the `_t` suffix is *not* just convention.  POSIX claims it as a reserved suffix.  Although it's not so unusual for folks to ignore that reservation, they do so at their own peril.

Comment: To quote [James McNellis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225386/if-i-do-a-typedef-in-c-or-c-when-should-i-add-t-at-the-end-of-typedefed) from the VS C++ Team @ Microsoft: `In POSIX, names ending with _t are reserved, so if you are targeting a POSIX system (e.g., Linux), you should not end your types with _t.`

Comment: This question is again one of those which should be separated into a C and a C++ part. POSIX is a C extension which is largely irrelevant to modern C++. You don't need `pthreads` if you have `std::thread`. And as far as C++ goes, there's an explicit recognition of `namespace ::posix`. The `_t` suffix should not be an issue outside `posix`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any answer for your first question, I believe it is just two different conventions that exist in the C++ standard.

For your second question, everywhere I'm aware of where `_t` or `_type` are used in the C++ standard they are used as a typedef for some underlying type. For example `uint32_t` is a typedef for the unsigned integer type that is 32 bits in size on the current implementation. They are never used for actual types.

I believe POSIX uses `_t` for actual types but that is a different convention and is separate from the use in the C++ standard.