# What's the meaning of `_t` of `size_t` in C?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a type followed by _t (underscore-t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

I know what the `size_t` is. It's an integer type depends on platform. But I cannot figure out what the `t` stand for. And there are many typed which suffixes with `_t`. What's the `_t` means?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"t" means "type" (or to some people, `typedef`, which is the command used to create them). `size_t` is the *type* used to specify memory sizes. `time_t` on the other hand, is the *type* used to specify time spans. They generally happen to refer to the same underlying type (a 64-bit or 32-bit integer, depending on the platform), but the label helps keep them straight conceptually so that the implementation details can be hammered out by the compiler.

For example, `time_t` used to be a 32-bit integer, meaning that the clock would roll over in 2038. But on most 64-bit architectures, they've expanded `time_t` to be a 64-bit integer, which means that 64-bit systems won't have a "year-2038" problem. Since code that deals with unix timestamps uses the type name `time_t` rather than `int` to refer to these values, everything will "just work" when you simply recompile the code for your new architecture.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience the _t is a conventional suffix for types declared using **typedef**.

e.g.

```
typedef int myInt_t;
```

etc...