# Meaning of _t postfix of sigset_t, time_t

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a type followed by _t (underscore-t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

I have seen many data structures in Linux environment have post-fix of '_t'.

Is there a specific meaning for it?

Comment: For many, it stands for habi<em>t</em> ;-) (Grr, how to bold just part of a word?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "type".

Comment: An allegedly system-reserved abbreviation. Your code shouldn't use it for its own types.

Answer (score 2):

The 't' stands for 'type'.  POSIX and possibly also C99 reserve all names ending in '_t' for implementation-defined typedefs.  Despite this, many libraries use such names for their own user-exposed types (I suppose such libraries could be considered part of the implementation, if you wish to look at it that way).