# meaning of known data types

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a type followed by _t (underscore-t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

Does anyone knows what the 't' in time_t, uint8_t, etc. stands for, is it "type" ?
second, why declare this kind of new types, for instance size_t, couldn't it be just an int ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the t is for Type.

The reason for defining the new types is so they can change in the future. As 64-bit machines have become the norm, it's possible for implementations to change the bit-width of `size_t` to 64 bits instead of just 32. It's a way to future-proof your programs. Some small embedded processors only handle 16 bit numbers well. Their `size_t` might only be 16 bits wide.

An especially important one might be `ptrdiff_t`, which represents the difference between two pointers. If the pointer size changes (say to 64 or 128 bits) sometime in the future, your program should not care.

Another reason for the typedefs is stylistic. While those size_t might just be defined by

```
typedef int size_t;
```

using the name `size_t` clearly shows that variable is meant to be the size of something (a container, a region of memory, etc, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think, it stands for type - a type which is possibly a typedef of some other type. So when we see `int`, we can assume that it is not a typedef of any type, but when we see `uint32_t`, it is most likely a typedef of some type. It is not a rule, but my observation, though there is one exception to this: `wchar_t` is not a typedef of any other type, yet it has `_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it probably stands for `type` or `typedef`, or something like that.

The idea between those `typedef`s is that you are specifying exactly that that variable is not a generic `int`, but it is the size of an object/the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch/whatever; also, the standard makes specific guarantees about the characteristics of those types.

For example, `size_t` is guaranteed to contain the size of the biggest object you can create in C - and a type that can do this can change depending on the platform (on Win32 `unsigned long` is ok, on Win64 you need `unsigned long long`, while on some microcontrollers with really small memory an `unsigned short` may suffice).

As for the various `[u]intNN_t`, they are fixed size integer types: while for "plain" `int`/`short`/`long`/... the standard do not mandate a specific size, often you'll need a type that, wherever you compile your program, is guaranteed to be of that specific size (e.g. if you are reading a binary file); those `typedef`s are the solution for this necessity. (By the way, there are also `typedef`s for "fastest integer of at least some size", when you just need a minimum guaranteed range.)