# Binary Tree Node - GCC Warning - Incompatible Types

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a new node for a binary tree, and I'm getting errors when I try to make an assignment to ->left and ->right.

```
typedef struct bin_node_t {
     data_t data;
     bst_key_t key;
     struct bin_node *left;
     struct bin_node *right;
} bin_node;
```

Is my struct definition for bin_node.

Here are the variables I'm using:

```
bin_node *new;
bin_node *node_array[256];
```

Here's my variable assignments:

```
/* ... code to initialize node_array ... */
new = (bin_node *)malloc(sizeof(bin_node));
```

and here's where I'm gettin an error:

```
    new->right = node_array[i+1];
    new->left = node_array[i];
```

and here is the compiler warning I'm getting:

```
huffman.c:99: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
huffman.c:100: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

My full code is available at:

http://pastebin.com/iPYP5uVt

Comment: Could it be that you forgot the `_t` in the left and right pointer declarations?

Comment: If you're going to use an `_t` suffix, it is more normal to use it in the typedef name than in the structure tag (or, when you use it in the structure tag, you also use it in the typedef name).  Hence `typedef struct bin_node { ... } bin_node;` or `typedef struct bin_node_t { ... } bin_node_t;` would be more conventional.  Be aware that [POSIX reserves the `_t` suffix for typedef names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/15168); you are nominally treading on thin ice using it, but many people blithely ignore this and most of the time they get away with it without any trouble.

Comment: Best practice is not to use `_t` at all in application code because this convention is reserved for C library types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `struct bin_node` in your code. Change `struct bin_node *left` to:

```
struct bin_node_t *left;
              ^^^
```