# Using mergesort to sort linked lists

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, mergesort

I am currently working on the mergesort algorithm. I have three functions. list_sort_merge, mergelist and splitlist. list_sort_merge calls the other two to split and merge the list. I am having trouble getting this to work correctly. 
So what happens when I run GDB is that I get through the split function and get each number by itself such as the following example:

```
427
42.7
4.2.7
```

Then the mergesort comes along and segfaults me. What happens is the right_list and left_list are not being passed to mergesort. Meaning when mergesort goes to compare in the function comp_proc, it says that they are both NULL.

I think the problem is coming from the split function.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The `holder = NULL;` assignments in `mergelist()` seem to be superfluous.

Comment: I did that for safety as I have not checked for memory leaks yet. I will test for that after i get the function working correctly.

Comment: OK.  Just looking for what's going on...and the questions arise.  In `left_list->current_list_size = list_size(list_ptr)/2; right_list->current_list_size = list_size(list_ptr)/2; if(list_size(list_ptr) % 2 == 1) { left_list->current_list_size++; }` could be simplified to: `right_list->current_list_size = list_size(list_ptr) / 2; left_list->current_list_size = list_size(list_ptr) - list_size(list_ptr) / 2;`.  It's a trick of sorts.

Comment: Okay very interesting. So this will cause the odd number to get into the left list? So like the example above?

Comment: This is *way* more complicated than it needs to be if all your doing is merge-sorting a linked list (a data structure that beautifully lends itself to that algorithm, btw).

Comment: I think it might help to post the data structures.  You've got a doubly-linked list; the `list_node_t` has both `prev` and `next` fields. You should create a function such as `void dump_list(FILE *fp, const char *tag, list_t *list)` which prints your list for you.  Use it to print what's going on in `split_list()`.

Comment: This is the only way I logically could get it done WhozCraig. Do you have any suggestions to simplify it? And I will post that

Comment: I'm about to start a dreadful commute home, but if this is still up this evening (US-PDT) I'll post something. Sorry to leave you hanging like that, but my wife trumps SO =P

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my splitlist seems to get it all the way down to where I think it should be. Its just when I try to call the right_list and left_list in the mergesort, they are both NULL

Comment: It is hard work filling in the blanks...Please research how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  The absence of your list implementation means we have to deduce what `list_access(left_list, 0)` means, what the `comp_proc()` is taking as arguments and what it compares; what `list_iter_front()` and `list_iter_back()` do.  Most of the others can be guessed fairly easily, but it is far harder work than should be expected.  It means we can't run the code at all easily, which also makes life more difficult than it should be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Im sorry about that. List access gets the value that each linked list is. Such as 4, 2 or 7. Comp_proc is just comparing the two heads of the lists. If it == 1 than the right list is bigger and it places the left list in to sort.

Comment: @philliesws10 Sorry that took so long. family stuff. Anyway, **very** simple example can be found [at this link](http://ideone.com/GHmT1j). Obviously with head+tail pointers, etc, additional housekeeping would be needed. It was the algorithm I wanted to get across, and with some intricate pointer work, it is wonderfully simple to merge-sort a linked list. I apologize it took so long and that I didn't clean up the memory leak, but I was in a bit of a rush to hammer it out for you. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reimplementing the list functions to suit myself because I couldn't work out how the interfaces to some of the functions in the code were supposed to work, even after the hints in the comments. The new code is still working with a doubly-linked list, but I renamed `list_node_t` to `node_t` and shortened `current_list_size` to `size`. There's a function to insert at the tail, and another to remove from the head; the other functions are fairly straight-forward.

There are now three files: the main merge-sort source code (`mergelist.c`), including a test `main()` program and the revised versions of the three functions in the question; the list header (`list.h`) defining the interface to the `list_t` type; and the list source code (`list.c`) implementing the `list_t` type.

The excitement is mostly in the main code, but the rest was necessary to get things to work.  The sort sorts in descending order (largest value first).  The crucial changes (that I recall, and other than the interface to the list functions) are highlighted in the code for `mergelist.c`.  The key debugging tool was the `dump_list()` function.  Something similar to that is a *sine qua non* for debugging sorts and lists and so on.

Strictly, type names ending in `_t` are reserved for the implementation (see [What does a type followed by `_t` (underscore t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)).

#### Sample output

Compiled with GCC 4.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.5, 64-bit pointers.

```
List Before (0x7FEC21C039A0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 10
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A00, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 9
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 2
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 7
 6: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 5
 7: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
 8: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 9: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 0
10: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Data 4
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C039A0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 10
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A00, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 9
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 2
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 7
 6: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 5
 7: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
 8: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 9: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 0
10: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Data 4
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03B20)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A40, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A00, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 9
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 2
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 7
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03B00)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 0
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Data 4
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B20)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A40, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A00, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 9
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 2
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 7
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A00, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A00, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 9
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A20, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A40, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 2
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 7
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A00, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A00, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 9
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039E0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A00, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039E0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 3
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03BE0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03BC0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039E0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039E0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 3
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03BE0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039C0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 1
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03BC0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039E0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039E0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 3
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039E0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 3
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 1
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C039E0, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 3
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 1
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A00, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 1
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A20, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A40, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 2
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 7
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A20, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A20, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 2
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A40, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A40, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 7
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A20, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A20, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 2
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A40, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A40, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 7
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A40, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A20, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 7
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 2
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 3
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 1
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A40, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A20, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 7
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 2
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B20)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 7
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 3
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 2
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 1
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B00)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 0
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Data 4
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 0
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Data 4
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A80, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 6
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A80, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 8
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03BE0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A60, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03BC0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A80, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03BE0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A60, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A60, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 5
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03BC0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A80, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A60, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 5
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A60, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 5
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 6
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A60, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 5
List -->>list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 0
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Data 4
List Split-L (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 0
List Split-R (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 4
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03B80)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 0
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03BA0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Size 1
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 4
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 4
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Data 0
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03B40)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03A60, Size 3
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 5
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03B60)
Head 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 2
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 4
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Data 0
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C03B00)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 5
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 4
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Data 0
-->>list_sort_merge()
List List-L (0x7FEC21C03B20)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C039C0, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 7
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 3
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 2
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 1
List List-R (0x7FEC21C03B00)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A80, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 5
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 8
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 6
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 5
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 4
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Data 0
<<--list_sort_merge()
List <<--list_sort_merge() (0x7FEC21C039A0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 10
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 8
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 7
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 6
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 5
 6: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 4
 7: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Data 3
 8: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 2
 9: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 1
10: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 0
List After (0x7FEC21C039A0)
Head 0x7FEC21C03A00, Tail 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Size 10
 1: Node 0x7FEC21C03A00, Next 0x7FEC21C03A80, Prev 0x000000000000, Data 9
 2: Node 0x7FEC21C03A80, Next 0x7FEC21C03A40, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A00, Data 8
 3: Node 0x7FEC21C03A40, Next 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A80, Data 7
 4: Node 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A60, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A40, Data 6
 5: Node 0x7FEC21C03A60, Next 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AA0, Data 5
 6: Node 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Next 0x7FEC21C039E0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A60, Data 4
 7: Node 0x7FEC21C039E0, Next 0x7FEC21C03A20, Prev 0x7FEC21C03AE0, Data 3
 8: Node 0x7FEC21C03A20, Next 0x7FEC21C039C0, Prev 0x7FEC21C039E0, Data 2
 9: Node 0x7FEC21C039C0, Next 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Prev 0x7FEC21C03A20, Data 1
10: Node 0x7FEC21C03AC0, Next 0x000000000000, Prev 0x7FEC21C039C0, Data 0
```

#### `mergelist.c`

The biggest problem in `splitlist()` was that the lists were not cleanly severed.  If you tracked down the left list, you traversed the right list too.  This could lead to problems — lots of problems, in fact.

```
#include "list.h"
#include <assert.h>

static void mergelist(list_t *list_ptr, list_t *left_list, list_t *right_list);
static void splitlist(list_t *list_ptr, list_t *left_list, list_t *right_list);

static int comp_proc(data_t d1, data_t d2)
{
    if (d1 > d2)
        return +1;
    else if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void list_sort_merge(list_t *list_ptr)
{
    if (list_ptr->size > 1)  // 1, not 0 — do not try splitting a singleton list.
    {
        dump_list(stdout, "-->>list_sort_merge()", list_ptr);  // Debug
        list_t *right_list = list_construct();
        list_t *left_list = list_construct();
        splitlist(list_ptr, left_list, right_list);
        dump_list(stdout, "Split-L", left_list);  // Debug
        dump_list(stdout, "Split-R", right_list); // Debug
        list_sort_merge(left_list);
        list_sort_merge(right_list);
        dump_list(stdout, "Sort-L", left_list);  // Debug
        dump_list(stdout, "Sort-R", right_list); // Debug
        list_ptr->head = NULL;
        list_ptr->tail = NULL;
        list_ptr->size = 0;    // Additional
        mergelist(list_ptr, left_list, right_list);
        list_destruct(right_list);
        list_destruct(left_list);
        dump_list(stdout, "<<--list_sort_merge()", list_ptr); // Debug
    }
}

static void mergelist(list_t *list_ptr, list_t *left_list, list_t *right_list)
{
    node_t *holder;
    fprintf(stdout, "-->>list_sort_merge()\n");
    dump_list(stdout, "List-L", left_list);
    dump_list(stdout, "List-R", right_list);
    while (left_list->size > 0 && right_list->size > 0)
    {
        assert(left_list->head != 0 && right_list->head != 0);
        /* Sort into descending order */
        if (comp_proc(left_list->head->data, right_list->head->data) > 0)
        {
            holder = list_remove_head(left_list);
            list_insert_tail(list_ptr, holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = list_remove_head(right_list);
            list_insert_tail(list_ptr, holder);
        }
    }
    while (left_list->size > 0)
    {
        holder = list_remove_head(left_list);
        list_insert_tail(list_ptr, holder);
    }
    while (right_list->size > 0)
    {
        holder = list_remove_head(right_list);
        list_insert_tail(list_ptr, holder);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "<<--list_sort_merge()\n");
}

static void splitlist(list_t *list_ptr, list_t *left_list, list_t *right_list)
{
    if (list_ptr->size > 1)
    {
        size_t temp = 0;
        node_t *holder = list_ptr->head;
        right_list->size = list_ptr->size / 2;
        left_list->size = list_ptr->size - right_list->size;

        left_list->head = list_ptr->head;
        right_list->tail = list_ptr->tail;

        while (temp < left_list->size)
        {
            temp++;
            holder = holder->next;
        }

        /* Make sure the two lists are separate — a major issue */
        right_list->head = holder;
        left_list->tail = holder->prev;
        left_list->tail->next = NULL;
        left_list->head->prev = NULL;
        right_list->tail->next = NULL;
        right_list->head->prev = NULL;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int values[] = { 1, 3, 9, 2, 7, 5, 8, 6, 0, 4 };
    enum { NUM_VALUES = sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]) };
    list_t *list = list_construct();

    //dump_list(stdout, "Empty list", list);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
    {
        node_t *node = node_construct(values[i]);
        list_insert_tail(list, node);
        //dump_list(stdout, "Inserting", list);
    }

    dump_list(stdout, "Before", list);
    list_sort_merge(list);
    dump_list(stdout, "After", list);

    list_destruct(list);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `list.h`

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>

typedef int data_t;

typedef struct node_t node_t;
struct node_t
{
    node_t *next;
    node_t *prev;
    data_t  data;
};

typedef struct list_t list_t;
struct list_t
{
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
    size_t  size;
};

extern node_t *node_construct(data_t data);
extern void    node_destruct(node_t *node);

extern size_t  list_size(list_t *list);
extern void    list_insert_tail(list_t *list, node_t *node);
extern node_t *list_remove_head(list_t *list);
extern void    list_destruct(list_t *list);
extern list_t *list_construct(void);
extern void    dump_list(FILE *fp, const char *tag, list_t *list);

extern void list_sort_merge(list_t *list_ptr);

#endif /* LIST_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### `list.c`

```
#include "list.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern node_t *list_head(list_t *list);
extern node_t *list_tail(list_t *list);
extern void    list_destruct(list_t *list);
extern list_t *list_construct(void);

size_t list_size(list_t *list)
{
    return list->size;
}

void list_insert_tail(list_t *list, node_t *node)
{
    assert(list != 0);
    assert(node != 0);
    if (list->tail == 0)
    {
        assert(list->tail == 0 && list->head == 0 && list->size == 0);
        list->tail = node;
        list->head = node;
        node->prev = 0;
        node->next = 0;
        list->size = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->next = node;
        node->prev = list->tail;
        node->next = 0;
        list->size++;
        list->tail = node;
    }
}

node_t *list_remove_head(list_t *list)
{
    assert(list != 0);
    node_t *node = list->head;
    if (list->head != 0)
    {
        assert(list->size > 0);
        list->head = node->next;
        if (node->next != 0)
            node->next->prev = 0;
        node->prev = 0;
        node->next = 0;
        list->size--;
    }
    return node;
}

void list_destruct(list_t *list)
{
    assert(list != 0);
    node_t *next;
    for (node_t *node = list->head; node != 0; node = next)
    {
        next = node->next;
        node_destruct(node);
    }
    free(list);
}

void dump_list(FILE *fp, const char *tag, list_t *list)
{
    assert(list != 0);
    fprintf(fp, "List %s (0x%.12" PRIXPTR ")\n", tag, (uintptr_t)list);
    fprintf(fp, "Head 0x%.12" PRIXPTR ", Tail 0x%.12" PRIXPTR ", Size %zu\n",
            (uintptr_t)list->head, (uintptr_t)list->tail, list->size);
    size_t i = 0;
    for (node_t *node = list->head; node != 0; node = node->next)
        fprintf(fp, "%2zu: Node 0x%.12" PRIXPTR ", Next 0x%.12" PRIXPTR ", Prev 0x%.12" PRIXPTR ", Data %d\n",
            ++i, (uintptr_t)node, (uintptr_t)node->next, (uintptr_t)node->prev, node->data);
}

list_t *list_construct(void)
{
    list_t *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if (list != 0)
    {
        list->head = 0;
        list->tail = 0;
        list->size = 0;
    }
    return list;
}

node_t *node_construct(data_t data)
{
    node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node != 0)
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = 0;
        node->prev = 0;
    }
    return node;
}

void node_destruct(node_t *node)
{
    free(node);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for that! I edited my code to have that but I for some reason am still getting a segfault when I enter the comp_proc part of mergelist. It says that they are NULL when I compare them.

Comment: Since I can't see your actual list functions or actual `comp_proc()`, I'm not sure what your problem is.  I cheated and passed the data members (integers in my code) directly to the `comp_proc`, so there are no pointers to be null in my code.  It wouldn't be hard to pass two nodes, though it is not really clear that the comparator should need to understand the `node_t` structure (`list_node_t` in your code).  It should be straight-forward to replace `typedef int data_t;` with `typedef char *data_t` and make appropriate changes in `comp_proc()` and `node_construct()`, plus printing code.

Comment: Okay I understand you. After GDBing it some more, I found that when it enters the mergelist function the data is NULL. Therefore it is not carrying over from the splitlist into it

Comment: `assert()` is your friend...along with the `dump_list()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html

and the example code:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c