# Way to shorten struct *pointerexample so that I don't have to type it out?

Tags: c, struct

I remember my professor showed us how to replace a "struct" statement such as `struct *pointerexample` so that we do not have to type it out each time. However, I don't remember if they used a preprocessor directive such as `#define` or how they did it. Any ideas? Also, how would I do `#define EXAMPLE struct *pointerexample`? Is that the correct way?

Comment: `struct *pointerexample` isn't even valid C. You might be thinking of `typedef`.

Comment: Because it omits the name of the structure.

Comment: @Caleb oh, right, the name of the structure isn't the pointer, the name of the object is, right?

Comment: `struct pe *` or `typedef struct pe pe;` then you can just say `pe *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a typedef:

```
struct pointerexample {};

typedef struct pointerexample *ppe;
```

With this, you can use `ppe` to create pointers to `pointerexample`:

```
ppe var1, var2;
```

Comment: Isn't `_t` a reserved suffix, as per the C-Standard?

Comment: @alk - it's reserved by POSIX. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent

Comment: @alk: Good point, I didn't know this was reserved by POSIX. I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct pointerexample SPE, * PSPE;
```

Now you can use `SPE` instead of the longish name. And better do not use `PSPE` as a pointer to the latter, as this is close to obsfucating code, in my opinion.

Using the pre-processor would do also:

```
#define SPE struct pointerexample
```

However this latter approach could lead to unexpected results under certain conditions. There is no need to use the pre-processor here, as there is the former solution.

Comment: @Caleb: Although it's really hard for me to `typedef` a pointer type, I did adjust my example.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to first use a `typedef` to reduce the amount of typing when declaring a struct. This allows you to just use a named type rather than having to use the `struct` keyword everywhere. eg:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  int a;
  char c;
} myStruct_t;

myStruct_t aStruct;        // Declare a struct
aStruct.a = 0;             // Set a to zero
myStruct_t* pS = &aStruct; // Pointer to a struct
pS->a=1;                   // Set a to one
```

Comment: The C syntax allows struct to be used without a name so I don't understand why coders give a name to the struct as well as typedefing it.  I see a lot of code where they give the struct a name but never ever use it.  I can see a use if the struct is recursive, but in this case, there is no need for it.

Comment: Style, in my case. Also, I usually wrap mine in preprocessor conditionals in case I have to port it to a C89 or older compiler, and the above doesn't work.