# uint32_t, int_t notation for representing variable size

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, notation

This question only is about the notation selection reason.

To [prevent bugs](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/barr-code/4008255/2/Bug-killing-standards-for-firmware-coding)  it is essential to mention the variable size in bits like

```
uint32_t VariableA;  // uint32_t has been type defined for architecture whose int size is 32 bit.
int16_t  VariableB;
```

instead of using only type specifiers like

```
int VariableName;
```

The question here is why is _t used in the uint32_t instead of only uint32. Where did this _t come that has been seen appended in the typedef?

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent.

Comment: Actually, it is a much better practice to use non-specific types like "int" or "size_t" whenever possible to avoid bugs. _However_ there are plenty of rubbish programmers out there who for example write "long" and really mean "32 bit signed integer" (and other rubbish programmers who write "long" and really mean "64 bit signed integer), and for these cases you should write what you mean, for example int32_t. For example size_t means "enough bits to hold the size of anything in memory".

Comment: And if you are programming in C++, use std::uint32_t and std::int16_t: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names were taken from the POSIX specification, which was widely used before C and C++ standardised the names of fixed-size integer types. POSIX uses a convention of appending `_t` to most type names.

Answer (score 1):

The `_t` convention comes from the early days of UNIX. Following suit, most (or all) aliases to scalar types and many `struct` types in Posix are named as such, and some such types are even standardized in C itself.

Posix furthermore reserves all names suffixed with `_t` in the C++ global namespace (or for C, just in general).

C++ does not introduce any new `_t` names to my knowledge, and best-practice use of the C++ standard library only introduces names into the `std` namespace.

At some point in the future, it is anticipated/hoped that Posix will be sandboxed in the `posix` namespace.

In any case, best practice is to keep all your interface `typedef`s in your own namespace, and once you've done that, naming aliases to scalar types with `_t` is quite a reasonable policy. The benefit is that C++ is often sensitive to whether two name refer to types that are really different (but maybe behave similarly) or they are really aliases to the same thing. `_t` is obviously an alias to something simple.

Comment: So `_t` is just to remind that it's actually a `typedef` of a more fundamental type.

Comment: @ajay Yup. Occasionally in Posix or C the original isn't fundamental, e.g. `mbstate_t`, but personally I avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`_t` basically denotes a `type` name. Therefore, you would be ill-advised to end variable or function names with `_t` since it could cause some confusion and even undefined behaviour(depending on compiler etc.)

**Addendum**

`POSIX` systems define a lot of extra type names ending in `_t`, and reserves the suffix for the implementation. Therefore when working on POSIX-related systems, defining your own type names with the convention is ill-advised and can lead to undefined behaviour