# Is there name for smallest unit of UTF-8 string?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, naming-conventions, naming

I'm porting an application that does not have Unicode support to have one. I've chosen UCS4 as an internal representation to simplify string processing by reusing existing codebase, as my application of interest does no tasks related to grapheme or visual cluster management, and may operate solely on codepoints, so it's affordable by now.

Existing application uses `char *` everywhere, so in the process I've established few types to replace `char *` used for all these cases, and no longer use `char *` explicitly:

1. **"plain bytes, may contain zeros and come with length"**. I describe these as `typedef uint8_t byte_t` and use as `byte_t *foo`. It's a direct replacement for `char *`, to be compatible with functions accepting both `void *` and `char *`.
2. **"mostly null-terminated characters of Unicode string"** — these are `typedef uint32_t ucs4char_t`. I handle such characters through own functions like `strnlen_ucs4(const ucs4char_t *s, size_t maxlen)`, which reimplement logic of original functions, but operate on whole UCS4 codepoints rather than 8bit chars.
3. and finally, **"bytes that are part of UTF-8 encoded string, not representing particular character/codepoint, implied to be zero-terminated, to be used as opaque buffers"** — I have trouble with naming this. Functionally it's the same as `byte_t`, but I want to emphasize these types serve different purposes and should not be mixed without explicit translation (despite the fact translation is no-op in this particular case). These units appear in "borderline" functions between Unicode world and OS/network/fs/whatever, which have a need to coerce UCS4 to OS-provided opaque zero-terminated strings (working with `getenv()`/`putenv()` as an example). I encode UCS4 into UTF8, so I can then use `strlen` or `strncmp`, which don't have to care about Unicode and *meaning* of compared contents.

But I don't know if there is any official name for such small unit, so for now I call it `utf8byte_t`, and I have a feeling that it's a misnomer.

So, is there any name to use? If none, maybe there is better approach to what I've described?

Comment: rfc 3629 just calls its an octet.

Comment: @nos, that could make sense, but naming something *octet* is just almost as generic as *byte*. However, Freenode user *@ihatehex* suggested to name them *tribble*s, which sounds good and is catchy :)

Comment: I would just call the former `char`. The latter is called `Rune` in the Plan 9 implementation of UTF-8, which is the original. A port for other operating systems is [available under a liberal license](http://swtch.com/plan9port/man/man3/rune.html).

Comment: [types ending with `"_t"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent) are reserved by some compilers - may want to use a different scheme.

Comment: You are asking for an official name for something described vaguely, in a manner that confuses general Unicode concepts and a specific programming language. Official as per whom for exactly *what*? Besides, as such, the whole question is off-topic, as it about terms, not a practical, answerable programmin question.

Comment: I suggest you read utf8everywhere.org. Maybe you would make different design decisions aboutu internal storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put things together.

Unicode strings are made of *code points*. Code point is just a number in open range `[0..0x110000)`, and has no defined binary representation. UCS4 allows to represent code point as *at least* 32-bit unsigned integer, but *only* for use in memory, because binary representation is not defined in UCS4. Alternatively, UCS2 represents code points as 16-bit unsigned integers, but truncates code space to open range `[0..0x10000)` (the *basic plane*), making it impossible to express characters in *supplementary planes*. UCS2 is, obviously, a subset of UCS4, and UCS2 has no binary representation defined as well.

That's what Unicode *transformation formats* (UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32) are for. They define rules for translating each *code point* into one or more *code units*, which *are* binary representation.

UTF-32 makes each code point translate into single 32 bit long code unit.

UTF-16 maps each code point to either one or two code units, 16 bit each. Two UTF-16 code units form *surrogate pair*, which then can be decoded into single code point. Surrogate pairs are used for characters in supplementary plane (that one UCS2 is incapable supporting of).

UTF-8 maps each code point to up to four (up to six in older Unicode standard) code units, each being exactly 8 bits.

---

So for my particular case, I should name this type `utf8codeunit_t`. I can't name it just `codeunit_t`, because code units are only defined in scope of their respective transformation formats. I still have no idea is there name for sequence of *code units* encoding single *code point* other than "UTF-xx encoded code point", but that's not important just now.

Comment: One thing the OP may not be aware of: a UTF-32 code unit does not necessarily correspond to one "character"

Comment: @rubenvb I am, as I've noted explicitly in my question that software I'm working on does no text processing in terms of graphemes or visual clusters. So I don't care about control characters, combining characters and so on — codepoints are the highest necessary level of abstraction for my task. But thank you for suggestion, this may be a catch for someone.