# Why does defining a typedef with the same name as a function give an error when the typedef is global but not local?

Tags: c, function, enums, typedef

When I compile the first code I don't get any error

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bool_t(void)
{
    printf("This is a test\n ");
}

int main()
{
    typedef enum bool_t
    {
        false=0,true=1
    } bool_t;

    bool_t x = true;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the second code I get an error

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bool_t(void)
{
    printf("la valeur est ");
}

typedef enum bool_t
{
    false=0,true=1
} bool_t;

int main()
{
    bool_t x = true;

    return 0;
}
```

The error is

`error: ‘bool_t’ redeclared as different kind of symbol`

I would like really to understand what happened exactly in the first and second code to understand more the behavior of the two implementations as I consider myself a beginner in C!

Comment: In the first case, `typedef enum bool_t` is local to the `main` function so in `main`'s scope the function `bool_t` is not accessible, but this of course doesn't answer your good question. On `gcc` if you enable `-Wshadow` Im pretty sure a warning will be issued. BTW, avoid `_t` suffix since it's reserved for system types.

Comment: Because in the first case you're in the same scope of `main`.

Comment: the `_t` is prefered to differ **variable** from **types** ! @iharob

Comment: Re: "the `_t` is prefered to differ **variable** from **types** !": No, iharob is correct. Although the `_t` suffix does mean "type", it's reserved for system types.

Comment: but I think it would be a good habit to rename new pattern with a different type by adding a suffix. Maybe `_type` would be better than `_t` ! for more about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case `bool_t` is declared inside a function scope, so it *shadows* declaration from outer scope. This is useful, because it means that adding independent symbols to outer scope won't make your function invalid.

In the second case you are declaring `bool_t` twice in the same scope - global scope. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

In first case your overriding global `bool_t` function with local enum type `bool_t`.

But in second case your are declaring `bool_t` twice in global scope, which is an error as compiler pointed you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to resolution of scope that's they called. In the first code you have used two same name but in different scope so they are treated as different and local variable gets preference.
     In the second case the scope is same global so declaring two same named variable with different data type the compiler would not allow it.