# How to store a struct member as big endian

Tags: c, struct, int, endianness, uint32-t

I have a `struct` similar to:

```
typedef struct _pair_t{
    uint16_t    keylen;     // 2
    uint32_t    vallen;     // 4
} __attribute__((__packed__)) pair_t;
```

I will be using `mmap` to read from a file, so I want to store the numbers as big endian.

Do I need to do `htobe16` / `betoh16` or there is some `__attribute__` that can do this for me?

Comment: Sidenote: You shouldn't define types that end with `_t` to avoid possible conflicts with built-in compiler types.

Comment: @Sidenote - I use hm_pair_t (I prepend hm_ everywhere I also use _t for all typedefs). Should I fix this in my code? Is there good howto for this kind of naming?

Comment: Names that start with `_` are also reserved.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/694733) has some discussion about it. I have used `CamelCaseWithSuffix_T` convention in C, but don't know if it's best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use htobe16 or htons or similar.  There's no way in most compilers to declare a variable as having a different endianness.

I'm aware of a (paid, commercial) compiler which had a switch to turn the entire program into the "opposite" endianness, but that's not quite what you want, and I'm sure you don't want to pay for it.