# Efficiency of structs of length 8, and uint64_t

Tags: c, performance, struct, compiler-optimization, pass-by-value

#### TLDR: are 8-byte structures handled just as efficiently as 8-byte uint64_t?

I have 3 data structures that are very similar. They are 6, 7 and 8 bytes long. I want to put them all in uint64_t variables. The goal is that comparisons and assignments will be very efficient. (These values are used as key in several (large) trees).

Example: I have defined the following data-structure, for the one that is 7 bytes long.

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    uint64_t raw;
    struct {
      uint8_t unused;
      uint8_t node_number;
      uint8_t systemid[SYSTEMID_LENGTH]; /* SYSTEMID_LENGTH is 6 bytes. */
    } nodeid;
  };
} nodeid_t;
```

I can now do quick assignments and copies via the raw union member.

```
nodeid_t x, y;

x.raw = y.raw
if (x.raw > y.raw) {
```

Etc, etc.

My question is about use in functions and in assignments.
When I pass this struct by value, will the compiler (gcc) recognize that these structures are 8 bytes long. And therefore treat as if they are int64_t?

Example: Will there be efficiency/performance differences between:

```
int64_t my_function();
nodeid_t my_function();
```

In other words, will gcc use 1 instruction to put a nodeid_t on the stack, as if it was an integer? Or will it create a loop, and copy 8 bytes one by one? Does this depend on -O optimization?

Same question for assignment.

```
int64_t a, b;
nodeid_t x, y;

a = b; /* One machine instruction, I hope. */
x = y; /* Also one instruction, or will it do a loop ? */
```

Comment: For reliable equality comparisons, you must ensure that the `unused` member is zero (or some other fixed value) at all times in all structures.  It is unusual, but not improper, to put the unused member first.

Comment: Sure. And I do that. I am sure I can deal with all these little details about getting the code semantically correct. My concern is efficiency. It would be so nice if I can pass these 8-byte structures around by-value, in stead of by-reference.

Comment: Why is this question only +2? Even regular expression questions get better scores than this.

Comment: "Will there be efficiency/performance differences" – why don't you try it? Compile some code using this technique and a raw `uint64_t`, then look at the generated assembly and profile it too.

Comment: Yep, I could have done that too. But it would take me a day or two. I haven't looked at assembly since 1984. I thought a quick question on stackoverflow would be just as good. Apparently not. :) And even with testing to figure it out, you never know for sure what your code will under slightly different circumstances. With biology or medicine, you need to test stuff to figure it out. With computer science, everything is man-made. So you should always be able to read the manual or the source code and know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot be certain that the `union` has the same size as `uint64_t`.

This is due to *packing* in the nodeid `struct`: compilers will often insert gaps between `struct` members. Some compilers allow you to change the packing arrangements but then your code will not be portable.

It would be safer to have an *array* of `uint8_t`: then the memory would be contiguous.

A compiler will then simply copy the memory on assignment, so you may as well use `nodeid_t` as your function return types.

Your second job is to rename `nodeid_t`: `_t` suffixes are reserved in POSIX C.

Comment: Which compiler would insert padding between `uint8_t` elements in a structure?  When the following element is also `uint8_t`, the 'often' is a massive over-statement and it would be tempting to replace it with 'never'.  If you were dealing with larger types, then the padding might be present — but only if the types in the structure are of heterogeneous sizes.  If all the members are the same size (or the elements of any array are the same size as the non-array elements), then a compiler will not insert padding.

Comment: If you're confident that your compiler will behave itself then it would be a very good idea to use a static assertion on the size of your structure.

Comment: or use __attribute(packed). Whatever the syntax in your compiler is.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan Leffler. I think that in this simple case, all compilers will generate a structure of length 8. If not, I can always use:  __attribute__ ((packed)) I guess. (I use that already when making structs for packets). Thanks about the suggestion of using the assert. I will do that. But I still don't know if 8-byte structures are just as efficient as 8-byte uint64_t.

Comment: Yes they are: A compiler will then simply copy the memory on assignment

Comment: About renaming my types ? I see <sometype>_t everywhere. I use a prefix for all my types. I just removed it here to make the examples more readable. Is there really anything wrong with using: isis_mystruct_t ?

Comment: Yes, it's *very*, *very* bad. Can't you delegate that task to a new hire :-)

Comment: Are you serious, or just kidding me ? I've see the _t suffix a lot in professional code. Old code, I must admit. And always in combination with using your own unique prefix. The other coding convention I have seen is to add the word "type" to the end of you type. Without an underscore. But I prefer isis_mythingy_t over isis_mythingytype.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent. Time to call that recruiter.

Comment: Just use a suffix like `*_ty` or whatever and you are fine. It's just `_t` which is reserved. Or just do not use a suffix at all: Capitalised IDs are types, all other are something else.

Comment: As long as your _t types are not in the global nor std namespaces you're good. All this discussion is purely theoretical - I assume you don't typedef size_t & co.

Comment: I'm perplexed as to the degree of complacency here. 1) C standard allows packing between `uint8_t` so please don't assume that compilers will not do it, and 2) `_t` suffix use goes beyond the theoretical. To a degree (1) can be discharged with static asserts and (2) by renaming all offending types. Both should be considered as bugs in your codebase which ought to be fixed before writing new code.

Answer (score 1):

Portability aside, if you're after the ultimate low latency, you're on the right track. I've been doing the same for many years.
A few things to note though:
1. Your code, with chars only, should work as is, because the alignment requirement for char is 1.
2. With wider types you'd need to pack struct nodeid. In gcc you do it with `__attribute__((packed))`. I think MSVC uses `#pragma push pack(1)...#pragma pop`.
3. Gcc used to have bugs around this area (gaps between bit fields, wrong alignment...) so I strongly suggest using compile-time checks, like `STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(nodeid_t) == sizeof(uint64_t))`
4. If some of the 8 bytes are not populated, make sure you put zeros or something in them. Otherwise your comparisons etc would use random values.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. However, I still don't know if gcc will treat 8-byte structs just as efficient as 8-byte integers.

Comment: Gcc definitely would with optimization > 0. This is not related to the union though. This is because you did not define copy-ctor so it's allowed to do bitwise copy.
The union with raw is still useful for putting it in containers instead of writing operators, hash functions, etc.

Comment: If gcc would make a loop there, somebody in the gcc team would have to commit seppuku.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your architecture. But assuming that you're on x86_64 (which is the most likely), you don't need to do the union hack for copying and function arguments (you'd still need it for comparisons).

```
struct foo {
    char a;
    char b;
    short c;
    int d;
};

void
foo_copy(struct foo *a, struct foo *b)
{
    *a = *b;
}


extern void bar(struct foo a);
void
foo_value(void)
{
    struct foo f = { .a = 1 };
    bar(f);
}
$ cc -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -S foo.c
$ cat foo.s
[... cleaned up ...]
_foo_copy:                              ## @foo_copy
    movq    (%rsi), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rdi)
    retq

_foo_value:                             ## @foo_value
    movl    $1, %edi
    jmp _bar                    ## TAILCALL
```

Different architectures will have different requirements, a strict alignment architecture for example wouldn't be able to do the copy unless the ABI requires larger than usual alignment. Other ABIs might have different calling conventions for structs. So this is hard to answer generally. But if you're on x86_64, you probably either don't need to waste time doing this optimization, or if you want the comparisons to be efficient, this will work like you want.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, efficiency will likely not be a concern.

That said, this will probably not do what you intend:

```
if (x.raw > y.raw) {
```

If you're running on a machine with a little-endian architecture, the least significant byte is stored first.  If that's the case, then if for example you have this:

```
x.nodeid.systemid[0] = 1;
x.nodeid.systemid[1] = 2;
y.nodeid.systemid[0] = 2;
y.nodeid.systemid[1] = 1;
```

Then `(x.raw > y.raw)` would evaluate to true.

Comment: I am aware of endianness. This is networking code. So I am always thinking about endianness anyway. I convert byte-order when reading and writing to packets. I already use #ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__, etc  in my current code when I do my comparisons on these 3 types.

Comment: "For something like this, efficiency will likely not be a concern". Do you mean that even if the compiler generates a loop to copy 8 bytes to the stack, it doesn't matter ? Or is there a chance that the (gcc) compiler handles this as integers ?

Comment: @Gryz  What I mean is that there's a good chance it doesn't matter.  The compiler to typically good at making whatever optimizations it needs without resorting to coding tricks.  In general, you shouldn't worry about micro-optimizations like this unless a profiler tells you that you should.

Comment: I agree about the profiler. :) However, these 3 types are used all the time. All the time. My code might grow to 50k lines. If it is beneficial to make these changes, I rather do it now. That's why I am asking. - In any case, I will switch from using pointers for these things, to passing value. Like a real opaque type. The compiler can then figure out how to copy structs.

Answer (score 0):

I am now inclined to define my 3 datastructures simply as typedef uint64_t.

```
typedef uint64_t isis_simple_item_t;
typedef struct isis_complex_item_t {
  byte_t unused;
  byte_t node_number;
  byte_t systemid[ISIS_SYSTEMID_SIZE];
};

byte_t number;
isis_simple_item_t nodeid;

number = ((isis_complex_item) nodeid).node_number;
```

This way I can do quick compares, assignement, function returns, function parameters-by-value, etc.

And then when I need to access one of the members inside the struct, which happens a lot less, I'll use wrapper functions. With casts inside them, from uint64_t to the more complex struct. That also means I don't need the union anymore.

Comment: `((isis_complex_item) nodeid)` is illegal. Perhaps you meant `*(isis_complex_item *)&nodeid`

Comment: I found out that that was illegal. I didn't expect that. I wrote that code here just as an example. And an hour later I started implementing it in my own code. And indeed got a compiler error. Weird, I hadn't expected that. (Normally I never did "optimization/ugly" stuff like we discuss here). I now have everything working in my code, in a nice way. I even hardly needed to use casts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this fancy footwork, why not simply use `memcmp`, this works for any contiguous data-type is probably implemented as a compile intrinsic so should be fast and definitely properly sidesteps the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: I already got my byte-for-byte copy working. There are 2 benefits to my approach: 1) I need to do a lot of compares. My trees might have tens of thousands of these keys, and a quick compare is a quicker search. 2) it would be so nice to do: "node1 = node2;" in stead of "isis_copy_nodeid(&node1, &node2);"