# How to create a new instance of a struct

Tags: c, struct, instance

What is the correct way to create a new instance of a struct? Given the struct:

```
struct listitem {
    int val;
    char * def;
    struct listitem * next;
};
```

I've seen two ways..

The first way (xCode says this is redefining the struct and wrong):

```
struct listitem* newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
```

The second way:

```
listitem* newItem = malloc(sizeof(listitem));
```

Alternatively, is there another way?

Comment: *"(xCode says this is redefining the struct and wrong)"*. There's something you're not telling us, since the first way is neither redefining the struct nor wrong.

Comment: @user3386109 oh you're right! XCode only said it's wrong because I was using it in a function, not main(). Not sure why though...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The second way only works if you used

```
typedef struct listitem listitem;
```

before any declaration of a variable with type `listitem`. You can also just statically allocate the structure rather than dynamically allocating it:

```
struct listitem newItem;
```

The way you've demonstrated is like doing the following for every `int` you want to create:

```
int *myInt = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: The simple convention to always: ``typedef Foo_tag { ... } Foo_t`` and using the ``Foo_t`` forthwith works pretty well in C programming. There is really only the typing cost for the ``typedef`` but afterwards it ammortizes by never having to type ``struct Foo_tag`` at all.

Comment: `struct listitem newItem;` is only static allocation if it occurs at file scope. At block scope this is automatic allocation.

Comment: @M.M You're correct of course, but in general terms, `malloc` and friends deal with dynamic allocation while other forms of allocation, regardless of placement within a file, is frequently referred to as "static allocation" to differentiate it from dynamic allocation.

Comment: @BitTickler Personally I don't care either way. I will note that `typedef struct List_tag List; struct List_tag { List *next, *prev; int data };` works even better for structures requiring pointers to items of the structure type being defined.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That is about the only time I ever use the ``struct tag_name``. When the structure needs pointers to self. ``typedef struct List_tag { struct List_tag *next;... } List_t;``

Comment: Please note that names ending in `_t` are reserved for the implementation and should be avoided. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12727104/1701799.

Answer (score 34):

It depends if you want a pointer or not.

It's better to call your structure like this :

```
typedef struct s_data 
{
    int a;
    char *b;
    // etc..
} t_data;
```

After to instanciate it for a no-pointer structure :

```
t_data my_struct;
my_struct.a = 8;
```

And if you want a pointer you need to malloc it like that :

```
t_data *my_struct;
my_struct = malloc(sizeof(t_data));
my_struct->a = 8
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the other answers I'd like to add two more compact ways of creating instances. Example:

```
struct Person{
    float position[2];
    int age;
    char name[20];
}
struct Person p1 = { {4, 1.1}, 20, "John" };
struct Person p2 = { .age=60, .name="Jane", .position={0, 0} };
printf("%s, aged %i, is located at (%f, %f)\n", p1.name, p1.age,p1.position[0], p1.position[1] );
printf("%s, aged %i, is located at (%f, %f)\n", p2.name, p2.age,p2.position[0], p2.position[1] );
```

output:

```
John, aged 20, is located at (4.000000, 1.100000)
Jane, aged 60, is located at (0.000000, 0.000000)
```

Note that for `p1` the order of properties matches that of the struct definition. If you don't want to type struct all the time when you use a type you can define a new alias using

```
typedef struct Person SomeNewAlias;
SomeNewAlias p1;
```

and you can call the new alias the same as the old namejust fine

```
typedef struct Person Person;
Person p1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
struct listitem newItem; // Automatic allocation
newItem.val = 5;
```

Here's a quick rundown on structs:
http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm