# Function to generate struct instances in c

Tags: c, struct, declaration, function-definition, flexible-array-member

How do I write a function that generates an instance of a previously defined struct every time it's called?
I'm sure since it's an easy problem no context is needed but here is what I have now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

time_t t;

char names[][40] = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};

struct fighter {
    int type;
    int strength;
    int dexterity;
    int resistance;
    int weapon;
    char name[];
};

struct fighter fighters[];

struct team {
    struct fighter f1;
    struct fighter f2;
    struct fighter f3;
    struct fighter f4;
    struct fighter f5;
    int wins;
    int losses;
    char name[];
};

struct fighter genf(){
    struct fighter genfighter;
    memcpy(genfighter.name, names[rand()], 40);
    return genfighter;
};

int main(){
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    scanf("%s");
    struct fighter f1 = genf();
    scanf("%s");
}
```

And I get this on compilation with gcc.

```
In function 'genf':
note: the ABI of passing struct with a flexible array member has changed in GCC 4.4.
At top level:
warning: array 'fighters' assumed to have one element.
```

When running it I get a segmentation fault after one scanf()

Comment: To "generate an instance" you need to allocate the memory *dynamically*. Also, are you sure that you want `name` be a FAM? That will add complexity.

Comment: You cannot create a local variable of such a struct type. There would not be any memory reserved for the flexible array part.

Comment: What do you this this statement does: `scanf("%s");`

Comment: `struct fighter fighters[];` You can also not have arrays without size except as last member of a struct. An array without elements does not make any sense.

Comment: You should turn up warning level a bit. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. That should at least warn about missing parameters for `scanf`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: what's _FAM_?

Comment: Flexible Array Member

Comment: Make `name` a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @Gerhardh I was trying to make an array of struct instances.

Comment: @Barmar is there no way you can use an array for this?

Comment: Not unless you give it a fixed size.

Comment: Since you seem to have a hard-coded limit of 40, it is going to be simplest to just use `char name[40]` in the struct definition.

Comment: Structures with FAM can only be used with dynamic allocation using `malloc()`.

Comment: I believe this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577808/how-to-create-a-new-instance-of-a-struct is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: You can do this sort of thing with a flexible array, but there does not seem to be any really benefit in doing so and it will be simpler to use a `char *` in the struct.  If you do use the FAM, you will almost certainly want to add a `capacity` or a `size` member in the struct.

Comment: Use `-Werror` along with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, always, no exceptions. Thank me later.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code.  You have a few bits going against you with the current code.  First off, the "rand()" function can produce a very large value which causes an array element that does not exist in array "name" to be accessed.  That's what is causing your segmentation fault.  Also, if you happen to get past that bit, you will have a buffer overrun when trying to store a "name" array element as the "name" variable in your structure basically doesn't have any length.  With that following is a tweaked version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

time_t t;

char names[][40] = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};

struct fighter
{
    int type;
    int strength;
    int dexterity;
    int resistance;
    int weapon;
    char name[40];  /* Need to define a size or a buffer overflow will occur */
};

struct fighter fighters[];

struct team
{
    struct fighter f1;
    struct fighter f2;
    struct fighter f3;
    struct fighter f4;
    struct fighter f5;
    int wins;
    int losses;
    char name[40];  /* Need to define a size or a buffer overflow will occur */
};

struct fighter genf()
{
    struct fighter genfighter;
    printf("Value: %d\n", rand());      /* To illustrate what type of number is generated */
    memcpy(genfighter.name, names[(rand() % 3)], 40);
    return genfighter;
};

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    //scanf("%s");
    struct fighter f1 = genf();
    printf("Fighter name: %s\n", f1.name);
    //scanf("%s");
    return 0;
}
```

Note the the character arrays have been given a size that should accommodate the storage of a name.  And a modulo value is derived from the "rand()" call to make sure that the index value will be valid.  Following was a test run.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Fighter/bin/Release$ ./Fighter 
Value: 1876063575
Fighter name: Name3
```

I did not address the single element warning from the compiler.  I will let you sort out the size of your structure array.  But give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a structure with a flexible array data member `name`

```
struct fighter {
    int type;
    int strength;
    int dexterity;
    int resistance;
    int weapon;
    char name[];
};
```

You need to allocate dynamically memory for an object of the structure type and its flexible array `name` if you want to store in the array data as you are doing in the function `genf`

```
struct fighter genf(){
    struct fighter genfighter;
    memcpy(genfighter.name, names[rand()], 40);
    return genfighter;
};
```

Otherwise the function invokes undefined behavior.

Also you may not have nested structures with flexible arrays as in this declaration

```
struct team {
    struct fighter f1;
    struct fighter f2;
    struct fighter f3;
    struct fighter f4;
    struct fighter f5;
    int wins;
    int losses;
    char name[];
};
```

As for this declaration in the file scope

```
struct fighter fighters[];
```

then it represents a tentative definition equivalent to

```
struct fighter fighters[1];
```

Pay attention to that you forgot to specify the second argument that corresponds to the format string `"%s"` in this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s");
```

So it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, scanf() requires a pointer to read into for each conversion specifier in the format string. You need:

```
char charstring[100]
scanf("%s", charstring)
```

However, this is still unsafe, because your user may enter more than 100 bytes, which would overflow the buffer. So this is better:

```
char charstring[100 + 1];
scan("%100s", charstring);
charstring[100] = '\0';
```

I recommend turning -Wall on: your compiler may only warn you here, but it will likely cause a crash!

Answer (score 0):

### *"is there no way you can use an array for this?"*

The arrays `char name[]` at the end of the `struct fighter` and `struct team` structures are of *incomplete type*. This is allowed as the last member of a `struct`, creating a *flexible array member* (or *FAM*). But, a `struct` with a member of incomplete type is itself of incomplete type. C does not allow creation of arrays with elements of incomplete type.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to choose a constant size for the `name` arrays which is large enough to accommodate expected names and to use regular array members of constant size to store the names. Before initializing these arrays the lengths of names should be validated and names which are too long handled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_SZ       20  // Small size for testing purposes
#define MAX_FIGHTERS  100

struct fighter {
    int type;
    int strength;
    int dexterity;
    int resistance;
    int weapon;
    char name[NAME_SZ];
};

struct fighter fighters[MAX_FIGHTERS];

struct fighter genf(const char *name) {
    // Ensure that all members are zero initialized.
    struct fighter genfighter = { 0 };
    size_t name_sz = strlen(name) + 1;  // add 1 for `\0` terminator

    // Can only copy at most `NAME_SZ` characters.
    if (name_sz > NAME_SZ) {
        name_sz = NAME_SZ;
    }

    memcpy(genfighter.name, name, name_sz);

    // Add terminating `\0` if needed.
    if (name_sz == NAME_SZ) {
        genfighter.name[NAME_SZ-1] = '\0';
    }

    return genfighter;
}

int main(void) {

    char names [][NAME_SZ] = {
        "Apocalypse Alan",
        "Burly Barry",
        "Cederick the Clever",
    };

    size_t names_num = sizeof names / sizeof *names;
    size_t fighters_num = 0;

    // Populate `fighters` array.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < names_num; i++) {
        fighters[i] = genf(names[i]);

        ++fighters_num;  // Increment number of fighters.
    }

    // Let's try to add a couple of names that are too long.
    fighters[fighters_num++] = genf("Cederick the Cleaver");
    fighters[fighters_num++] = genf("Derrick of Doubtful Kindness");

    // Show names of fighters in `fighters` array.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fighters_num; i++) {
        printf("Fighter #%zu: %s\n", i+1, fighters[i].name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running the above program yields:

```
$ gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic fighterstructs.c 
$ ./a.out 
Fighter #1: Apocalypse Alan
Fighter #2: Burly Barry
Fighter #3: Cederick the Clever
Fighter #4: Cederick the Cleave
Fighter #5: Derrick of Doubtful
```

Note that the last two names that were added, "Cederick the Cleaver" and "Derrick of Doubtful Kindness", are too long to be stored in a `names` array (which at present holds 20 `char`s, or a string of maximum length 19). But the `genf` function checked to see if the name would fit in a `names` array before applying `memcpy`, only copied the initial portion of the name that would fit, and made sure that the result was null-terminated. "Cederick the Cleaver" is only one `char` too long; the array holding this string must be 21 `char`s long. If this was copied without checking length then code would write past the end of the `name` array, causing undefined behavior. Copying only the first 20 `char`s avoids a buffer overflow, but the resulting array is not null-terminated. An additional check must be made to ensure that a null-terminated array is created.

Finally, make sure that you always compile code with a generous number of warnings enabled. A good start is `gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.