# Allocating memory for structs, 2 different ways?

Tags: c

I am new in C, but not new in programming. Is there a difference between the 2 sets of codes ? If there is not, is there a convention on which one to prefer ? Is there a performance difference ?

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} something_t;
```

-

```
something_t* s;
s = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
s->x = 1;
s->y = 1;
```

or

```
something_t* s;
s->x = 1;
s->y = 1;
```

Comment: What makes you think the second way works? The first is incomplete too, you MUST always check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL` before dereferencing..

Comment: @iharob Does it really not work ? Wow. I would have sworn it worked when I tried it, but it indeed looks like it just crashes when I run that code now.

Comment: Your last set will cause a segfault because you haven't allocated any storage for `s`. In the first, you are simply creating an *alias* to `something_t` and in the middle, you actually have a structure in memory. **note** with the `typedef` or with a `stuct something_t {...};`, you can simply statically declare an instance and take advantage of automatic memory management (e.g. `something_t my_t;`, then `mt_t.x=1;`)

Comment: @Shiro, it works is a very complicated thing to say about a [tag:c] program. You might want to read about **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That would mean using the "stack" is that right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You are going to be using memory, your only alternatives are a static declaration with automatic memory management from the stack, or a dynamic declaration from the heap. Both have their uses. Unless you have an unknown amount of memory required to begin with, or need to return a block of memory from within a function, a static declaration is usually the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good way to do it is

```
something_t *something;
something = malloc(sizeof(*something));
if (something == NULL)
    please_do_not_use_something_perhaps_return_NULL_or_quit();
something->x = 2;
something->y = 2;
```

This way, you ensure the size is right and the code is more maintainable. And you also prevent a disaster by checking that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL` giving you chance to do something about it. Assuming *no-errors* is wrong all the time, in this because you never know when the system will run out of RAM.

Your second example doesn't work, this

```
something_t *something;
something->x = 2;
something->y = 2;
```

Invokes **Undefined Behavior**, one of the possible outcomes is that it "*Works*". So you might think that it worked because of undefined behavior, but the truth is, it's wrong.

In this case `something` doesn't point to valid memory, so you don't know for sure what the value of `something` is and it can be anything, thus the behavior of such program is unpredictable.

Also, [read why you should avoid `_t` as a suffix for type names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/1983495).

Comment: Interesting. I was using the `_t` because I saw it on the Quake 2 source code, which I am using as an "example" code, which I assume is well written and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, the first version should be

```
something_t* s;
s = malloc(sizeof(something_t));
s->x = 1;
s->y = 1;
```

instead of manually fiddling with the size of individual members; the second versions performs no allocation at all and accesses uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
something_t* s;
```

does not allocate any memory for your structure, it only allocates a pointer (to a random memory area). It is very likely it will trigger a segmentation fault when you try to read/write to it.

The good way to allocate your memory is

```
something_t* s;
s = malloc(sizeof(something_t));
```

or the one-liner

```
something_t* s = malloc(sizeof(something_t));
```

Don't forget to use `free(s);` when you're done with it.

If you want stack-allocation, you can use :

```
something_t s;
s.x = 2;
s.y = 2;
```