# Using input in the main body so the user can edit

Tags: c, input, enums, program-entry-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum Race {wood_elf, human, high_elf, khajiit, orc, dwarf};

enum Class {archer, assassin, healer, knight, mage, paladin};

typedef struct Character
{
    char name[20];
    enum Class class_;
    enum Race race_;
    int perception;
    int stealth;
    int strength;
    int charisma;
    int agility;
    int intelligence;   
    int health;
    int magika;
    int stamina; 
} Character;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int mc = 1;

    while(mc != 2) {
        printf("Welcome to Ceatures and Computers, please enter a number to select an option: \n\n");
        printf("1.) Create Character \n");
        printf("2.) Quit \n");

        scanf("%i", &mc);

        if(mc == 1)
        {
        }

        if(mc == 2)
        {
            printf("Thank you for playing. \n");
        }

        if(mc > 2)
            printf("Please enter number 1 or 2 to select a menu option. \n");
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I'm currently trying to make a text based game and am at a University. I'll be leaving soon and thought I'd try this site to see how useful it could be when I won't be able to ask teachers. The current part I am working on is letting the user input their character name, class, race, along with skills that have a max amount and total sum, much like Fallout. Hopefully this goes well and I can come back to this site for help and have more knowledge to help others.

Comment: What if `mc` is less than `1`?

Comment: Always check the return value from `scanf()`; if it says '0', it may mean the user type `a` where you wanted them to type `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.
some **recommendations**:

if user enters text like 'one', what happens?
**always check for errors**:

```
if (scanf("%i", &mc) != 1){
    printf("incorrect input.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

also check if user entered value is correct. and if not take appropriate action.

use this:

```
typedef struct{
    //...
} Character;
```

instead of (this is superfluous naming in your case):

```
typedef struct Character{
        //...
} Character;
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're driving at with the `typedef` suggestion (I can guess, but I'm not sure).  Note that [using `_t` as a suffix for a type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/) is reserved for the system if you use any POSIX headers, so you shouldn't use the convention for your own types.  I'm not convinced by your 'last but not least' comment either — I don't agree with it (not least because printing such values requires `<inttypes.h>` and the macros such as `PRId32` or `PRIX32`).