# In Python, what is `sys.maxsize`?

Tags: python, memory, max-size

I assumed that this number ( `2^63 - 1` ) was the maximum value python could handle, or store as a variable. But these commands seem to be working fine:

```
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>> a=sys.maxsize + 1
>>> a 
9223372036854775808
```

So is there any significance at all? Can Python handle arbitrarily large numbers, if computation resoruces permitt?

Note, here's the print-out of my version is:

```
>>> sys.version
3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Comment: "The largest positive integer supported by the platform’s Py_ssize_t type, and thus the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and many other containers can have." https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html The 3 site description is more vague. I'm not sure if it's the same in 2 and 3.

Comment: The maximum number of elements a list can contain. It is not the largest value an `int` can have, but the largest *index* the basic structures can contain, since outside this scope, it is no longer addressable.

Comment: Integers can be arbitrarily large in python, yes. Python is great for project euler. Obviously it's not infinite -- if the integer itself won't fit in memory, you can't do that.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Python can handle arbitrarily large integers in computation. Any integer too big to fit in 64 bits (or whatever the underlying hardware limit is) is handled in software. For that reason, Python 3 doesn't have a `sys.maxint` constant.

The value `sys.maxsize`, on the other hand, reports the platform's pointer size, and that limits the size of Python's data structures such as strings and lists.

Comment: It's the width of the address register: the number of different memory locations that the processor can physically refer to.

Answer (score 8):

## Documentation for sys.maxsize:

> An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type Py_ssize_t can take. It’s usually 2**31 - 1 on a 32-bit platform and 2**63 - 1 on a 64-bit platform. [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize)

> The largest positive integer supported by the platform’s Py_ssize_t type, and thus the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and many other containers can have. [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

## What is `Py_ssize_t`?

It is an index type (number type for indexing things, like lists). It is the signed version of size_t (from the C language).

- We don't use a normal number/ int, because this is unbounded in Python.
- In Python, we don't use `size_t` because we want to support negative indexing, in Python we can do `my_list[-4:]`. So `Py_ssize_t` provides negative and positive numbers between a range.
- The `_t` stands for type, to inform developers that `size_t` is a type name, not a variable. [Just a convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent).

## So what is the effect of having a limit on `Py_ssize_t`? Why does this limit list, strings, dict size?

- There is no way to index a list with an element larger than this. The list cannot get bigger than this, because it won't accept a non `Py_ssize_t`.
- In the dictionary case, `Py_ssize_t` is used as the hash. Python doesn't use linked lists in its dictionary implementation, it uses Open Addressing/ probing, where if a collision is found, we a systematic way of getting another place to find the key and put the value. So you can't have more than `Py_ssize_t` in a dictionary in Python.

In all practical cases (64 bit machines aka. probably you), you will run out of memory before you max out `Py_ssize_t`. Trying `dict.fromkeys(range(sys.maxsize + 5))` never got there, it just slowed my computer down.