# Why does the maximium size of containers have a sign bit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, containers, size, signed

I checked the help for `sys.maxsize` in Python 3.6:

```
>>> help(sys)
[...]
maxsize -- the largest supported length of containers.
```

Testing it:

```
In [10]: '{:,}'.format(sys.maxsize)
Out[10]: '9,223,372,036,854,775,807'

In [11]: math.log2(sys.maxsize)
Out[11]: 63.0
```

It's 63 bits, which suggests a leading sign bit. However, the length of a container cannot be negative.

What's going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138632/in-python-what-is-sys-maxsize

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate; the suggested post simply says *that* `sys.maxsize` is the maximum container size, not *why* it's 63 bits, rather than 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of a container was increased in Python 2.5 from 2<sup>31</sup>-1 to 2<sup>63</sup>-1. [PEP 353: Using ssize_t as the index type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/), which introduced the change, [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/#why-not-size-t):

> **Why not size_t**
>
> An initial attempt to implement this feature tried to use size_t. It
>   quickly turned out that this cannot work: Python uses negative indices
>   in many places (to indicate counting from the end). Even in places
>   where size_t would be usable, too many reformulations of code where
>   necessary, e.g. in loops like:
>
> ```
> for(index = length-1; index >= 0; index--)
> ```
>
> This loop will never terminate if index is changed from int to size_t.

So, the limitation stems from the decision to use a Python-specific "indexing" type, which it was convenient to define as signed (ssize_t) rather than unsigned (size_t) in order to ease the handling of negative indices.