# passing struct pointer to function doesn't modifiy the references

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Motive: Passing struct to functions such as we can reference it and modify its original pointer.

```
typedef struct thing{
    char x;
}thing_t;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f1(thing_t *bob, thing_t *boby) {
    bob->x = 'y';
    boby = bob;
    printf("f1 boby after: %c\n", boby->x);
}

int main(void) {
    thing_t *foo, *foofy;
    foo=(struct thing_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct thing));
    foo->x = 'x';
    printf("foo before: %c\n", foo->x);
    f1(foo,foofy);
    printf("foo after: %c\n", foo->x);
    printf("foofy after: %c\n", foofy->x);
    return 0;
}
```

the output are:

```
foo before: x
f1 boby after: y
foo after: y
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

as you can see:

```
boby = bob;
```

these wont modify pointer foofy, so it wont get any reference. I want foofy->x valued as y. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that names ending in `_t` are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent), so you shouldn't name your own types that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foofy` is pointing to nowhere in `main()`. The value it contains is indeterminate (some garbage value).  That's why when you tried to access it - it resulted in segmentation fault. Accessing memory that you were not allowed to access.

If you want to make changes to `foofy` pass `&foofy` or address of `foofy` and then make changes to it.

```
void f1(thing_t *bob, thing_t **boby) {
    bob->x = 'y';
    (*boby) = bob;
    printf("f1 boby after: %c\n", (*boby)->x);
}
```

You will call it like this

```
f1(foo,&foofy);
```

The output will be when these changes are made is

```
foo before: x
f1 boby after: y
foo after: y
foofy after: y
```

Also you won't see the changed value of `x` for the struct `bob` same way. 
***C is pass by value.*** That's why in earlier case a copy of the passed argument is the object on which we made changes in the called function. Changes in copy won't make it happen to reflect those changes in the object in `main()`.

Few things that you need to do is - 1) Casting the return value of `malloc` is not needed. 2) Check the value returned by `malloc` in case it returns `NULL` handle it separately.

Answer (score 0):

`foofy` is structure pointer and it's not initialized , where it's pointing ? that's why below statements is giving `seg.fault`.

```
printf("foofy after: %c\n", foofy->x);
```

Assign valid address to `foofy` first then you can perform `foofy->x`

Note : when you are calling `f1` function , you may thought by catching with `thing_t *boby`,  `foofy` also get initialized, it's not. `boby` is local struct pointer and its valid in `f1` function only.