# Why are type keywords ended with "_t" suffix?

Tags: c++, types, naming, suffix

I understand that `size_t` has `_t` suffix since its alias/`typedef`. However I can't understand for what reason `char16_t`, `char32_t` and `wchar_t` contains `_t` suffix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a type followed by \_t (underscore-t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

Comment: `size_t` dates back to the ancient days of C. Everything else came on for the ride.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but that provides historical background. C++ is a separate language with a shared history

Comment: @Caleth: The question is not a duplicate, but the answer is the same: Because POSIX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [`wchar_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/):

> In C++, `wchar_t` is a distinct fundamental type (and thus it is not defined in `<cwchar>` nor any other header).
>
> In C, this is a typedef of an integral type.

For `char16_t` and `char32_t`, defined in [`<cuchar>`/`uchar.c`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cuchar/):

> In C, this header defines two macros: `char16_t` and `char32_t`, which map to unsigned integral types of the appropriate size (the same as `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`, respectively).
>
> In C++, `char16_t` and `char32_t` are fundamental types (and thus this header does not define such macros in C++).

So, in both cases, even though they are fundamental types in C++, they keep the `_t` for compatibility with C, where they were typedefs or macros.

Comment: Aw, now that makes sense. Thanks!