# How to use decltype on private class-members?

Tags: c++, c++11, typeof, decltype

I have a class with some "hairy" private fields. There are accessor-functions (getters and setters) for each.

```
private:
    array<double, 9>         foo;
public:
    const array<double, 9> & getFoo() const { return foo; }
    void                     setFoo(const array<double, 9> & _foo) { foo = _foo; }
```

I'd really like to *not* have to keep repeating the `array<double, 9>` elsewhere -- using `decltype` to refer to the type of the field, whatever it might be.

Unfortunately, simply invoking `decltype(instance.foo)` does not work outside the class, because `foo` is private.

Fortunately, `decltype(getFoo())` *almost* works -- `getFoo` is public and has to have the same type.

Unfortunately, the above "almost" is not good enough -- `getFoo`'s type is actually *a reference* (`array<double, 9> &`).

How do I get the actual type in the code outside of the class so that I can, for example, call the setter-function:

```
  SOMETHING values;
  for (auto &i : values)
      i = something();
  instance.setFoo(values);
```

Comment: Why not have a public type alias, like `using my_array std::array<double, 9>;`? Then you can just use `my_array` everywhere instead of having to use `decltype` every time.

Comment: `auto f = x.getFoo();` ?

Comment: @user463035818, don't want to call `getFoo()` before calling the `setFoo()` -- `foo` may not be initialized yet...
@FrançoisAndrieux, I have several different such members in the class -- having a separate type for each will be a bit messy :( Unless, of course, there is no other way.

Comment: Member is internal representation, methods are defining interface - you should not blindly make your methods represent members. You should not have getter and setter for each member either - it is basically the same as making them public convoluted way.

Comment: "There accessor-functions (getters and setters) for each." just make members public, implementing encapsulation this way is prophanity

Comment: if you really persist in avoiding to use type alias, you can remove reference: `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(getFoo())> values;`

Comment: Thanks, @AndriyTylychko, I had to wrap that in `std::remove_const_t` too, but then it worked!

Comment: Having getters and setters like that means you're basically just using this member as raw data storage. So why not simply make `foo` public? Does the whole thing even have to be a class with private members? Since you apparently have client code work on object interna directly, there can't really be much this class does in terms of encapsulation. Maybe the whole thing should rather be just a plain struct with all public members!? It usually adds to the readability of the code to not have to call getters and setters all over the place…

Comment: To answer Slava's and Michael Kenzel's question, using getters/setters allows changing the field later. This is irrelevant to the topic, please, do not continue on this tangent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `decltype` with type modifier:

```
std::decay_t<decltype(instance.getFoo())> values; // std::array<double, 9>
for (auto &i : values)
    i = something();
instance.setFoo(values);
```

Comment: `decay_t` is even "better" than combining the removal of const and removal of reference. Thank you!

Comment: Found out the hard way, `decay_t` is a C++14 thing. Works with g++-8.x, but not with 4.8.x...

Comment: @MikhailT.: `/*typename*/ std::decay<T>::type` in C++11.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        using array_t =          std::array<double, 9>; 
    private:
        array_t                  foo;
    public:
        const array_t  &         getFoo() const { return foo; }
        void                     setFoo(const array_t & _foo) { foo = _foo; }
};
```

Allows you to give the type to the user and allows you to not have to type `std::array<double, 9>`.  You also get the benefit of being able to change the type in one place only.

In outside code you could declare a variable of the class member type like

```
Foo::array_t bar;
```

Comment: Like `typedef`, this achieves, what I want -- but at the extra cost of having to declare such types. Why can't I refer to the existing declarations (of the methods and/or fields)?

Comment: I knew I'd find another solid answer from you worth upvoting! 
Not a big fan of all the horizontal spacing in OPs and by extension your code, though. Items should be physically situated in the manner they should be read rather than how it appears aesthetically (Thanks, Bob Martin)

Comment: @MikhailT. Classes are weird.  inline function definitions aren't complete until the class is defined.  Given that it is just easier to add a type alias in the class scope and use that then trying to use `decltype` (at least I find it so). It's also nice that you can give the type to the user.  If you don't want the user to know the internal type then you can just make the alias private.

Comment: @AndyG -- not even in the code outside of the class?

Comment: @AndyG Thanks.  Think I should use the "default" spacing?  I was considering it.

Comment: i was using `xyz_t` all over the place until i read that `_t` is reserved by POSIX, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent/231789) (question is C, but same applies to C++)

Comment: @user463035818 As long as the names are scoped correctly it is not an issue.  I this case it is scoped to the class so it can't conflict with the POSIX type.  This is also another reason why pretty much all user code should be defined in a namespace, especially if you are writing a library that others will use.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, after writing my comment I was reconsidering it, and realized that if you properly scope the names there is no problem, and if you dont then you are doomed anyhow. I think I will switch my habit again, writing `_type` is just too long ;)

Comment: @user463035818 It is more an issue in C as they don't have the scopes we have.  With class scope and namespace scope you should be free to defined your own `_t` types and save your fingers those 3 extra keystrokes ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is little context to your code, but usually you would just name things according to their meaning, like for example in:

```
struct my_image {
    typedef std::array<int,900> raw_image_t;
    const raw_image_t& get_raw(){ return data;}
private:
    raw_image_t data;
};
```

Now users can write

```
my_image::raw_image_t x = f.get_raw();
```