# Opaque structure with flexible array member

Tags: c, linux, struct

Suppose I have a struct declaration in a header file like:

`event.h`

```
struct event_t;
```

and in the corresponding C file I would like to sort-of alias it with the Linux-specific `struct inotify_event`. The problem is that `struct inotify_event` contains flexible array member:

```
struct inotify_event {
    int      wd;      
    uint32_t mask;    
    uint32_t cookie;  
    uint32_t len;
    char     name[];   
};
```

As per `6.7.2.1(p3)`  (emphasize mine):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
>   function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
>   itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except
>   that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
>   containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
>   **shall not be a member of a structure or an element** of an array.

it is not possible to define the `struct event_t` as

```
struct event_t{
    struct inotify_event base; //Non-conforming
};
```

So I could convert `struct event_t *` to `struct inotify_event *`. Since the `6.7.2.1(p3)` concerns only about structs the solution I see is to redeclare the tag name as

```
union event_t
```

and then define it later as a single element union.

```
union event_t{
    struct inotify_event event; //Conforming?
};
```

The only requirement the Standard imposes on union that I found is that the set of members of a union must be non-empty `6.2.5(p20)` (emphasize mine):

> A union type describes an overlapping **nonempty set of member objects**,
>   each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct
>   type.

***QUESTION:*** Is it a conforming/common way to hide an implementation details of some specific data structure through `union`?

Comment: Is there a reason to use `unions` specifically?

Comment: @Ameen In my case? No, the only reason I used it was to "alias" a sturcture with a flexible array member.

Comment: The common way of hiding implementation of a structure in C is through a opaque pointer.

Comment: handling opaque structures is usually done by handing pointers to that structure.

Comment: @P.W So this sort of declaration along with a function returning a pointer to the union as `union event_t * poll_events();` should be fine, right?

Comment: I think so, if you must need an alias. Otherwise, you can use pointer to the structure itself.

Comment: Also, the alignment of `char name[];` is probably 2. If `inotify_event` gets cast to a different type, like `inotify_event_handler` and `name` is the name of a function that gets called, then you will need to ensure `inotify_event.name` is aligned for a function pointer. Similar holds with casting to other types, where you may use `name` as a `size_t`. (OpenLDAP/Berkley DB does a lot of it, and it is very dirty when testing with `-fsanitize=undefined`).

Comment: @SomeName: I stand by my observation that §6.7.2.1 ¶3 as a whole is about unions as well as structures — unions are explicitly mentioned twice in the text you quote.  However, I believe you are probably talking about a small part of ¶3, not the whole.  I'm going to remove my previous comments; they're not helpful, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the simplest technique is to put this into your `event.h` header:

```
typedef struct inotify_event event_t;
```

This declares that there is a structure type `struct inotify_event` and declares an alias for it `event_t`.  But it does not define the content of `struct inotify_event` at all.

Only the implementation code in `event.c` includes the definition of `struct inotify_event` from the system header; everything else does not include that header and cannot access the elements of an `event_t` except through the accessor API you define.

You can enforce this separation of duties by code review — or by checking with `grep`, or other similar techniques — to ensure that no code except the implementation of your event type uses the system header for `inotify_event`.  And, if you port to a system other than Linux without support for inotify, then you simply provide an alternative opaque structure type in place of `struct inotify_event` in your `event.h` header.

This avoids all questions about whether there are flexible array members within structures, etc; it is all a non-issue.

---

Note the Q&A about [What does a type followed by `_t` (underscore t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent) . Be cautious about creating your own types with the `_t` suffix ¸— consider using a prefix on such type names that gives you a chance that your names will be distinct from those provided by the system.

Comment: So aliasing with opaque `union`s is not really common technique? The thing that bothers me a little bit is that switching to other platform without `inotify` would require manual checking...

Comment: Porting to a platform without inotify is going to require manual checking anyway, at least the first time you do it.  You could even use a structure tagged `inotify_event` on that platform, one of your own devising.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen the 'opaque `union`' technique used.

Comment: I agree. After thinking about for a while it I understood that such a `typedef` is much simpler and more concise than `union`/`struct`-like hacks in that particular case.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

**event.h**

```
struct event_t;
event_t *create_event(void);
void free_event(event_t *ev);
```

**event.c**

```
#include "event.h";

event_t *create_event(void)
{
    inotify_event *iev = ...;
    return (event_t *)iev;
}

void free_event(event_t *ev)
{
    inotify_event *iev = (inotify_event *)ev;
    // free the event
}
```

However, if you want to store additional data with the event then:

**event.h**

```
struct event_t;
event_t *create_event(void);
void free_event(event_t *ev);
```

**event.c**

```
#include "event.h";

struct event_t
{
    inotify_event *iev;
    // additional data
};

event_t *create_event(void)
{
    inotify_event *iev = ...;
    event_t *ev = malloc(sizeof(event_t));
    ev.iev = iev;
    return ev;
}
void free_event(event_t *ev)
{
    inotify_event *iev = (inotify_event *)ev.iev;
    // free the event (iev) first
    free(ev);
}
```

If you have multiple implementations that you need to hide in `event_t` then:

```
enum event_type
{
    EVENT_TYPE_INOTIFY,
    EVENT_TYPE_INOTIFY2,
};
struct event_t
{
    event_type type;
    union {
       inotify_event *iev; // you use this when type == EVENT_TYPE_INOTIFY
       inotify_event2 *iev2; // you use this when type == EVENT_TYPE_INOTIFY2
    }
    // additional data
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Single element union makes no sense. The purpose of union is to serve as a kind of polymorphic struct. struct members are accessed by offset, this is why is impossible to put an incomplete struct or array in the middle of a struct.

For example

```
struct foo { int a; int b[]; int c; };
```

In this example is impossible for the compiler to determine the address of `c` because `b` size can vary at runtime. But if you put incomplete array at the end all struct members address can be determined by the address of the start of the struct. Keep in mind that pointers are just address, so you can have any pointers to any structs and all the offsets can be determined, but you will need to deal with extra alloc/free stuff.

When you create an union you telling to compiler *Hey! I have this members, reserve enough space for me so that I can treat this variable as foo or bar*. In another words, the compiler will take the largest union member and this will be the size of the union. A common use for union is for representing multiple kinds of values.

```
typedef union { int integer, float real, char *string } value_type;
```

This way you can treat `value_type` as `int`, `float`, or a `char` pointer. You're code need to know the how to treat each member but the compiler will make sure that when you do `malloc(sizeof value_type)` you have enough space for the tree types.

Now your problem. You want to hide implementation details. Usually this is done by declaring a type or struct incompletely in a header, and completely only on your object files. Because of this when the user include your header all the information that the compiler has is `struct my_struct;`. It can't tell the size of `my_struct` so is impossible for you to allocate it as `malloc(sizeof struct my_struct)`. Also since the user hasn't the member definitions it can't mess up with the struct internals.

Working like this you will need to provide user with functions for allocating and freeing `my_struct`, for example `struct my_struct *foo = my_struct_new()` and `my_struct_destroy(foo)`.

You're already doing this. To deal with the `struct inotify` problem I would do one of these.

(1) Surround OS specific with `#ifdef` for that OS, so that the `event_t` has only the right members defined depending on the operating system. You will need `#ifdef` on your functions. This has the advantage to keep useless code out of final binary, so smaller footprint.

(2) Have pointers to OS specific structs and let runtime decide what to do. This easier to maintain.

Comment: So is it non-conforming to declare a single element `union`? If it is not, can you please give a reference. The Standard defines union as "_an overlapping nonempty set of member objects_". No notes about that the set of members should consist of 2 or more.

Comment: Is not non-conforming, but since union provides polymorphism between it's members, having a single member has no advantage