# Opaque struct that is declared but never defined

Tags: c, pointers, struct, language-lawyer

Say I have the declaration of

`my_header.h`

```
struct my_struct;

struct my_struct* my_struct_create();
void my_struct_use(struct my_struct*);
void my_struct_delete(struct my_struct*);
```

In case we define them as follows in `my_header.c`:

```
struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib;

struct my_struct* my_struct_create(){
    struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib *ptr = //create object
    return (struct my_struct*) ptr; //valid pointer conversion, ok
}
//void my_struct_use and void my_struct_delete definition omitted
```

***QUESTION***: Does the following code cause UB:

```
struct my_struct *ptr = my_struct_create();
my_struct_use(ptr);
```

I think it does. Even though the Standard permits us converting pointers that are correctly aligned `6.3.2.3(p7)`:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

The `struct my_struct*` and `struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib*` are nevertheless incompatible types `6.7.6.1(p2)`:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically
>   qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

So accessing (reading) `struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib *` through an lvalue of type `struct my_struct *` in the statement `struct my_struct *ptr = my_struct_create()` should cause UB. Does this reason make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Techincally, that depends on what `my_struct_use` does. However, if it's sane and all it does is cast back to the correct type like this:

```
void my_struct_use(struct my_struct *ptr)
{
    struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib *use = (struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib*)ptr;
    // ... use ptr
}
```

then there is no Undefined Behaviour. You're never accessing an lvalue of type `struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib *` as any other type. Inside `my_struct_use`, `ptr` is actually of type `struct my_struct *` (it's been produced by a cast, which produces a new value). It is then perfectly OK to cast this (back) to `struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib *`, again producing a new value of that type.

It *would* be Undefined Behaviour if you did this instead:

```
struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib * use = *(struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib**)(&ptr);
```

Then, you would be accessing `ptr`, which is an object of type `struct my_struct*`, through an lvalue of type `struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib*` (produced by dereferencing the result of the cast).

Comment: Actually I thought that `struct my_struct *ptr = my_struct_create()` is reading the pointer returned by `my_struct_create()` into a local variable of type `struct my_struct *`. But this seems to be not the case.

Comment: @SomeName But the pointer returned by `my_struct_create` is already of the type `struct my_struct*` - just look at the function's return type. It's a separate value of that type, produced by "value-casting" from a different type (but that's what casts are for).

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, if your C file has

```
typedef struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib my_struct;
```

then it is fine, otherwise it is undefined behavior.

Alternatively you can define `my_struct` to contain `some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib` as its first member.

All that matters is how you convert between pointers in the .c file and how you access the data.

Comment: Where exactly is it undefined and why? Converting the pointer to opaque struct pointer and back again is well-defined and yeilds the pointer comparing equal to the original pointer.

Comment: _Alternatively you can define my_struct to contain some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib as its first member._ This is not always possible. In case the struct contains flexible array member. I tent to replace struct with union here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293617/opaque-structure-with-flexible-array-member in this question

Comment: @SomeName Well obviously `my_struct` can't be another, incompatible type. The compiler may incorrectly assume all manner of weird things if that's the case. It all depends on how you access the data though. If `my_struct*` is just some weird placeholder dummy type instead of `void*` and you always cast back to `some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib` before accessing, then it is fine. But in that case you should do the typedef shown above.

Comment: Yes, `my_struct` can't be, I agree. But Im operating on pointers to `struct`s. If such a convertation is UB can you give an example of _A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type_?

Comment: Anyway why is putting `typedef struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib my_struct;` in header better then using opaque `void *` placeholder (`struct my_struct*`). We can define the `struct my_struct*` points to whatever we want without touching the header file.

Comment: @SomeName Use a type that makes sense. If the 3rd party struct type is what you use, then use that type.

Comment: Understood! `typedef struct some_struct_came_from_3rdparty_lib my_struct;` looks like much simpler solution, thanks.