# Why does a C++ class name stop being syntax highlighted when moved to a namespace in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

No C++ namespace type is being highlighted properly in VS Code. Specifically, when I move a correctly highlighted type from global namespace to another namespace, it's no longer highlighted.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in VS Code itself or with the *cpptools* extension?

EDIT: I just found out that it was the renaming of the type from `foo_t` to just `foo` that broke the syntax highlighting. So apparently type names ending with `..._t` are properly highlighted, but removing that also removes syntax highlighting. is this expected or a bug?

Comment: I didn't vote to close but I'd suggest you file a [bug-report](https://github.com/atom/language-c/issues).

Comment: Let me do some shameless advertising because I really like  the [ReSharper Visual Studio plugin for C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/). It analyzes C++ programs better than Intellisense, improving navigation, syntax highlighting, searching usages and (the reason I installed it) refactoring (did you ever want to rename a `getValue()` member function in one specific class but not in the 29 others?). ReSharper shines specifically in your area when it comes to tracking names through inheritance hierarchies, typedefs, usage declarations and templates. [I'm in no way affiliated, btw.]

Comment: Oh, I should add that I am not sure whether ReSharper works with VS *Code*. Edit: [Doesn't look like it.](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206010179-Is-there-any-plans-for-Resharper-to-support-VS-Code-)

Comment: The question was originally about namespaces, but since the edit, is about the "_t" suffix.  That makes the question title misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Semantic coloring did not exist for C++ in VS Code until version [0.24.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/0.24.0) which was released on July 3 of this year.

Previously it was all regular expression-based which is why `_t` types could be colored, but other user-defined types could not.

Answer (score 0):

According to my observations, only namespaces and typedefs ending on "_t" are highlighted as expected. Additionally, it does not matter where the namespace or typedef definition is located at.

Edit: Highlighting of "_t" is a POSIX thing, where all type definitions end on "_t". So it seems like there is no highlighting for types outside of those which comply to the POSIX naming convention.

[image: main test file I base my observations on]

Comment: `_t` is a [POSIX thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent). Why wouldn't it be a special thing in the highlighter?