# C Structures Explain push_vlan = (struct vlan_header *)((uint8_t *)new_eth + eth_size);

Tags: c

Can someone explain what is line of code does

```
struct name* push_tag = (struct name *)((uint8_t *)name2 + int_size);
```

where name and name2 are different structures .

Comment: "...where name and name2 are different structures" - what is that supposed to mean? `name` is obviously a struct tag, while `name2` is obviously a variable of pointer type. They are incomparably different. Calling them "different structures" makes no sense.

Comment: It is an assignment. `push_t` gets a new value. (push_tis a bad name,BTW)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. BTW the code is just a template of my original code.

Comment: To expand on what @wildplasser said, the `_t` suffix is a convention for user defined *types*, not for variable names.

Comment: Pretty sure that what it does is *undefined behaviour*

Comment: @TSG on the contrary, `_t` is reserved by POSIX for the [*implementation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/918959).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, nice catch. To clarify my *previous* comment: types use the `_t` suffix, not variable which are instances of those types.

In practice, however, the suffix is often used by users to define types too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code puts in the struct variable push_t the value of name2 + int_size, by doing a cast on different variables

Answer (score -1):

Taking a clue from your heading that this is networking code, what you are likely looking at is a packet decoder.   In this case, it has noticed that the ethernet frame (wikipedia) has had a vlan header pre-pended to it.  The code is skipping past this header to inspect the encapsulated packet.

Somebody pointed out that this is the dreaded Undefined Behaviour.  I am not certain whether the observation that virtually all systems code, including the internet, relies on what is now Undefined Behaviour speak more about the integrity of the worlds computers and networks or the delusional belief that standards bodies are somehow beyond reproach.   I have been on standards working groups; and am living evidence that they aren't that bright.