# Why is my loop creating extra linked list nodes?

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, getc

I'm working with linkedlist. I want to create a loop that allows the user to add nodes to the list. My output always has two extra blank nodes. I believe it has something to do with the way I am using the input functions to both take input and cancel the loop but I can't pin point where the problem is.

I've tried a variety of variations including terminating as loop expression and with while(1) terminating inside the loop.

I hope it doesn't matter that I'm using Ubuntu on Windows 10 but who knows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node * next;
} node_t;

node_t * init_node();
void print_list(node_t * head);

int main(){
  node_t * new = init_node();
  node_t * head = new;
  int c;

  printf("\n\tAt any time Press 'N' to quit.\n");
  do{
    if(c == 'n' || c =='N') {
      break;
    }
    //__fpurge(stdin);

    printf("\n\tEnter a value for the new node: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &new -> val);
    new -> next = init_node();
    new = new -> next;

  } while(c = getc(stdin) != 'N' && c != 'n');

  printf("\n\t");

  print_list(head);

  return 0;
}

node_t * init_node(){
  node_t * temp = (node_t *) malloc( sizeof(node_t *) );
  temp -> next = NULL;
  return temp;
}

void print_list(node_t * head){
  node_t * current = head;
  printf("\n\t");
  while(current != NULL){
    printf("%d->",current -> val);
    current = current -> next;
  }
  printf("null\n");
}
```

With inputs: 1, 2, 3 ...

The desired output is:
 >
1->2->3->null

The current output is:
>
1->2->3->0->0->null

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc. Don't add spaces around `->`.

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables suffixed with `_t`. They are reserved for special use. Here give a read to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent

Comment: Also I don't know what reason to give for this, but avoid giving name `new` to a variable. `new` is a keyword in `c++`. Most programmers reading your code with get a little confused on seeing it first.

Comment: You may find [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) helpful.

Comment: The `if(c == 'n' || c =='N')` is redundant, since `c` won't be `n` at the start of the loop (but you should initialize it to something), and it won't be by the next time you loop since the `while` clause will get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every loop, you do this:

- `new->val = user_input`
- `new->next = new_node()`
- `new = new->next`

So, every time, you add a new, uninitialized node at the end of the list. This happens to be `0` in your current system, but need not be.

Initially your list contains:

```
[?] -> null
```

The ? represents *uninitialized data*, which *happens to be* 0, and [] represents the node `new` points to.

When you input `1` on your first loop, you:

- change the ? into 1
- create a new `next` node with uninitialized data
- make `new` point to it

So your list contains

```
1 -> [?] -> null
```

Then you input 2 and get:

```
1 -> 2 -> [?] -> null
```

Finally, `print_list` will perform like this:

```
[1] -> 2 -> ? -> null

Prints `1 ->`

1 -> [2] -> ? -> null

Prints `2 ->`

1 -> 2 -> [?] -> null

Prints `0 ->` // But could print anything.

1 -> 2 -> ? -> [null]

Breaks the loop and prints `null`
```

Additionally, your `malloc` is asking for space for `node_t *`, which is a pointer to your data structure; you should be calling `malloc(sizeof(node_t))` or `malloc(sizeof(*temp))`. It is possible you're overwriting something by accident.

And I will assume the second zero comes from the way you're using your program: If you are pressing: `1`, `enter`, `enter`,`2`, `enter`, `enter`, `3`, `enter`,  `enter`, [nothing], `enter`, `n`, then `scanf` will receive an empty string and evaluate is as `0`.

You should check `scanf`'s return value: it reports how many fields were successfully matched.

A better way to handle user input might be:

```c
while (1) {
    char user_input[BUFSIZE];
    fgets(user_input, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    if (sscanf(user_input, "%d", node->val)) {
        ...
    } else if (user_input[0] == 'n' || user_input[0] == 'N') {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Preferably it would be `node_t *temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);` using the derefernced pointer to set the typesize eliminates all chance of mistake.

Comment: Good idea. Edited the answer.