# What are the naming exclusions in C++

Tags: c++

C++ has some key words that cannot be used to name variables, functions, classes, namespaces, etc.

For example:

```cpp
int class; // not okay

int operator; // not okay

int classX; // okay

int operatorX; // okay
```

The first two would work for C.

I want to know all the naming exclusions or exceptions so that I can be wary and not accidentally use them.

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers.  Trying to find if there is a duplicate on this site.

Comment: This seems like a disingenuous question. 'So that I can be wary and not accidentally use them.' If you use them, you'll immediately get a compilation error. This is not a problem that programmers face is practice.

Comment: If you want to be extra wary, you should extend your list with reserved compiler names (or naming convention).  Also, don't use `using namespace std;`, instead, only list the names you are using, e.g: `using std::cout;`.

Comment: Don't forget to add to your list any symbols or naming conventions used by external libraries or frameworks.  For example, QT likes to preface symbols with `Q`.  I'd rather go with Jasper's method and let the compiler notify me if I have duplicated a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The 'forbidden names' are known as *reserved words* or *keywords*, and they are listed in a number of places, such as on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

You can also refer to the "Keywords" section of any C++ Standard; here's one [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) that's available online (see Section #2.11).

EDIT: There are also other restrictions on the names of variables (and other *identifers*) in C++, like names beginning with a digit or a double underscore. More on these can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) (as linked in the [comment by Nathan Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver)).

Comment: reserved words and keywords aren't the only forbidden name.  `7fourths` is not reserved or a keyword but it is not a valid name.

Comment: What about naming conventions or keywords that are reserved for compilers?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a list of reserved names according to the C++17 standard. "Reserved" means that conforming programs must not declare these names. If a program declares one of these names and compiles, then the program has undefined behavior.

- Keywords. A list can be found [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)
- Identifiers that start with two underscores ([lex.name]/3.1)
- Identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter ([lex.name]/3.1)
- Names in the global namespace that start with an underscore ([lex.name]/3.1)
- Any name within namespace `::std` (including nested namespaces) ([namespace.std]/1)
- Any name within namespace `::posix` (including nested namespaces) ([namespace.posix]/1)
- Any name within a namespace `::stdX` where `X` is a nonempty sequence of digits ([namespace.future]/1)
- Any name in the global namespace that is part of the standard library ([extern.names], [extern.types]). In particular, even if, for example, your implementation's `<cstdio>` header contains only `std::printf` and not `::printf`, you are still not allowed to declare your own function called `::printf`. The reservation still applies even if your program does not include the header.
- User-defined literal functions whose suffix identifiers do not start with an underscore ([usrlit.suffix]/1)

In addition, the following reservations by the C standard library are assumed to be incorporated into C++ (in C++, the reservation should only apply at global scope):

- Names that begin with `isX`, `memX`, `strX`, `toX`, or `wcsX`, where `X` is a lowercase letter (C11 7.31.2/1, 7.31.12/1, 7.31.13/1)
- Names that both end with `_t` and also begin with `int` or `uint` (C11 7.31.10/1)

If targeting a POSIX platform, all names that end with `_t` are reserved (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727104) for reference).

There are additional restrictions on macros.