# Second access on malloced struct property crashes the program

Tags: struct, malloc

I tried using malloc on this table - struct that contains rows that contain cells. First I allocate the table, then succesfully add and initialize first row, but when trying to set cell count on second row it crashes - I have no idea why, probably some leftover from previous pointer? Or do I need to allocate memory even for props of the structs? This is my first time digging into malloc, so sorry if it is something trivial.

```
typedef struct cell_t
{
    char* content;
    int contentLength;

} cell_t;

typedef struct row_t
{
    cell_t* cells[100];
    int cellCount;
} row_t;

typedef struct table_t
{
    row_t* rows[100];
    int rowCount;
} table_t;

row_t* allocateRow()
{
    row_t* allocatedRow;
    allocatedRow = malloc(sizeof(row_t*));
    if (allocatedRow)
    {
        printf("THIS PRINTS TWICE");
        allocatedRow->cellCount = 0;
        printf("THIS PRINTS ONCE");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAILED TO ALLOCATE ROW!");
    }
    return allocatedRow;
}

void addRow(table_t* tableToAddTo, int nToAllocate)
{
    while (tableToAddTo->rowCount < nToAllocate)
    {
        tableToAddTo->rows[tableToAddTo->rowCount] = allocateRow();
        tableToAddTo->rowCount++;
    }
}

int main()
    {
        table_t* inputTable = malloc(sizeof(table_t));
        if (inputTable)
        {
            inputTable->rowCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("FAILED TO ALLOCATE TABLE!");
            return 1;
        }
        addRow(inputTable, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < inputTable->rowCount; i++)
        {
            free(inputTable->rows[i]);
        }
        free(inputTable);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You must not use the _t notation for your own type as explained there -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In allocateRow() change

```
allocatedRow = malloc(sizeof(row_t*));
```

into

```
allocatedRow = malloc(sizeof(row_t));
```

And you will need to allocate cells or change

```
cell_t* cells[100];
```

into

```
cell_t cells[100];
```

Comment: Aha! I was allocating size of a pointer! It works now, thank you very much :)
By the way if I change the cells to not include the pointer, shouldn't I do it for the rows too? I was thinking that I would allocate the cells the same way I did rows to table.

Comment: It depends on the size of the data but if you want to pratice with malloc...