# Is there a char8_t in C?

Tags: c, char8-t, c23

I have searched in many sites and did not get anything. I know that char8_t is a keyword in C++ since C++20. I am trying to find out in C, are they typedef-ing `unsigned char` to `char8_t` in C23 (with the release of [u8 character literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant)). Can anyone clarify me.

Comment: I don't think so. You could do `typedef uint8_t char8_t` to achieve a similar effect (though I wouldn't recommend making your own `_t` types due to POSIX reserving them.

Comment: [It was proposed for C2X](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2231.htm), but the new standard is not yet complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for a `char8_t` type (or typedef) has not yet been added to C23.  I submitted [N2231](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2231.htm) to add it back in 2018, but was not able to attend any meetings to argue for it then.

EDIT: 2021-06-06: [N2653 (char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings (Revision 1))](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2653.htm) has been submitted for C2x.  Implementations of that proposal are available for gcc [here](https://github.com/tahonermann/gcc/tree/char8_t-for-c) and for glibc [here](https://github.com/tahonermann/glibc/tree/char8_t).  Patches submitted to gcc and glibc can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2021-June/572022.html) and [here](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-June/127230.html) respectively.

EDIT: 2022-07-06: Implementations of the library portions of [N2653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2653.htm) have finally [landed](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=8bcca1db3d7c0dc900a4cad4054c1439baf73684) in glibc for the 2.36 release expected in August.

EDIT: 2022-12-30: [N2653 (char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings (Revision 1))](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2653.htm) was accepted for C23 during the January/February 2022 WG14 virtual meeting and wording is present as indicated in the [N3054 C working draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf). Compiler support is present in the in-development branch of gcc that will be released as gcc 13 in April or May. Compiler support is also present in the in-development branch of Clang that will be released as Clang 16 in March or April.

[N2653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2653.htm) doesn't just propose the `char8_t` typedef.  It also proposes that the type of `u8` string literals be changed to `char8_t`/`unsigned char` to match `u8` character constants, that the `mbrtoc8()` and `c8rtomb()` functions from C++20 be added, and that some atomic related macros and types be added.

Comment: I think the "C++23" above should be "C23" from the context and from the following link to a WG14 (C) paper.

Comment: @textshell, yes, that should have been C23, thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such things but you can have it with a typedef, as `char8_t` is equivalent to `unsigned char`:

```
typedef unsigned char char8_t;
```

You now have a `char8_t`.

*NB: I originally answered offering to use a macro (define), but for data types, typedef is the way*

Comment: A `typedef` would be better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Consistency with other type names (as in `<stdint.h>` et al), and a general preference for using core language features rather than the preprocessor.

Comment: After further reading I totally agree, sorry for the blunder.

Comment: Did you consider other platforms except for Linux?

Comment: What is wrong with other platforms? It's only some other languages (like Java) that think that char is more than 1 byte (from what I know).

Comment: I think @prehistoricpenguin means whether a `char` is an octet or not (`sizeof (char)` should always give 1 though because it checks byte-wise, but not necessarily one octet). Personally I've never seen any platform where a `char` isn't an octet but I don't know. For Linux though, POSIX guarantees `CHAR_BIT` to be 8.

Comment: Yes I understood the same way, and I  have also never seen any platform where `CHAR_BIT` is not 8, would be happy to be proved wrong

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Old mainframes and DSP

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 [`sizeof( [[un]signed] char )` is always one](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4): "When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1."

Comment: Note that `char8_t` is [POSIX reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/2410359), but OK in standard C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am aware of this, and I explained this in my comment. I actually got this knowledge from [this helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8) and note that in the top answer, there is this quote from Harbison and Steele: "It is permitted (if wasteful) for an implementation to use 32 bits to represent type char. Regardless of the implementation, the value of `sizeof(char)` is always 1."

Comment: Looks like there will be a `char8_t`, as per some committee meeting Jan/Feb 2022. See the current working draft https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3054.pdf. Might want to delete this answer since it's outdated.