# Is there any difference between using char (plain char) or signed/unsigned char to store characters in C?

Tags: c, string, char, character

I have a question, I have read some post here in SO that asks for help about when using `char`, when using `signed char` or `unsigned char`; in that post, they answered that to store characters we must use `char` and for using small data use `signed`/`unsigned char`, but, for what I know, `char` is implementation defined, so it can be equal to `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

The question is, can I use `char` or `signed char` or `unsigned char` to store characters?
If the answer is "No you cant", my next question will be, why? can you explain me the reason for use strictly `char` (plain char) to store characters?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you're working with plain text, you probably want to use plain `char`, because most of C's string-related functions are defined to work with `char` or `char *`.  If you're working with raw bytes, and especially if you're doing some math to combine adjacent bytes into multibyte integers, it's often extremely useful to declare everything as `unsigned char` or `unsigned char *`, because you avoid lots of annoying issues having to do with sign extension.

Comment: Use `char` for characters and thereby strings. Use `unsigned char` for low level raw data. Especially when using bitwise operators `unsigned char` should be used. Use `signed char` in (the seldom) case where you want signed calculations on a small data type.

Comment: You got some great answers below.  Make sure you to accept the best one, or comment on the answers that you feel fall short.

Answer (score 2):

`char` is guaranteed to always be large enough to store what's called *the basic character set*, which are the basic latin letters and symbols used in English. For example 7-bit ASCII. So as long as you use to store text only, you don't need to worry about its since and signedness.

Problems only appear when you use `char` for storing raw data, or when you use it in arithmetic. In that case, signedness might matter and since we can't portably know the signedness of `char`, it is unsuitable for such purposes. [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

The best type to use when dealing with raw data bytes is `unsigned char`/`uint8_t`. Similarly, use this when doing unsigned arithmetic on 8 bit types.

`signed char`/`int8_t` is pretty much only used when doing signed arithmetic on very resource-constrained systems such as 8 bit CPUs.

The reason why `unsigned char` isn't used universally is historical. C actually treats `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` as 3 different types. For example `unsigned char x; char*y = &x;` isn't valid, we have to make an explicit cast in order for it to work. However, on the binary level all character types alias with each other. So if we were to pass a `unsigned char` array to for example `strcpy`, it will work just fine but we need to cast the argument to `char*`, which is a bit tedious. Better then to keep all text in `char` type and avoid such casting.

(Theoretically the character types can be larger than 8 bits and then the `int8_t`/`uint8_t` types aren't present. But this exotic scenario is only relevant when writing C for certain DSP systems.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between using `char` (plain char) or `signed/unsigned char` to store characters in C?

**Yes, yet ...**

Use of `>>, *, /, %` creates differences when the character object is some signed character and negative vs. the unsigned character same bit-pattern positive.

Assignment to `int` can have an unexpected sign extension with negative characters.

`is...()` invokes *undefined behavior* (UB) when the character argument is negative (and not `EOF`).

The cases for `_Generic` distinguish between `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`.

Pedantic: With archaic non-2's complement using *signed* characters, user code often does not properly distinguish between +0 and -0 for the *null character*.

Signed types have more implementation defined behaviors than unsigned types when converting to other types, thus reducing portability.

"signed char are at a [disadvantage](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2653.htm) with respect to working with UTF-8 encoded text".

... Other issues too.

**... not always**

`str...()` behave as if the character was `unsigned char` regardless if `char` is *signed* or *unsigned*.  This is important in some functions, like `strcmp()` as when the difference in a *string* involves a negative `char`.

`"%c", "%s"` in `*scanf(), *printf()` matches all 3 types (or pointers to them).

<strike>There are no padding bits with the 3 character types and they consume the same space, although the soon to be dropped non-2's complement encodings allow for a trap representation for *signed* character types.</strike>

---

> ... can i use `char` or `signed char` or `unsigned char` to store characters?

Yes.

The *string* manipulation, `char` has the advantage in matching `str..()` function signatures.

For logic and raw byte code, use `unsigned char`.

Use `signed char` when small signed values are needed.

[@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766608/is-there-any-difference-between-using-char-plain-char-or-signed-unsigned-char/74769305#comment131953940_74766608), [@Support Ukraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386427/support-ukraine)

---

> If the answer is "No you cant", my next question will be, why? can you explain me the reason for use strictly char (plain char) to store characters?

N/A

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation defined if char is signed or unsigned as you said.

If you need a particular version specify it.  ASCII is 7 bits so for that it doesn't matter.  If you need 8 bit or more (like UTF-8) it *depends* on how you use the data.  For example left shift is well defined for unsigned values, but implementation defined if the left operand is negative.  `if(ch < 0)` is a no-op for unsigned but may matter greatly for signed.

In the upcoming C 2023 standard the new type `char8_t` may be of interest to you.  It is unsigned and the same as `unsigned char`.

Comment: Any reference about `char8_t`?

Comment: Hmmm, I did find https://stackoverflow.com/a/66973420/2410359

Comment: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf is the sep 3, 2022 draft.