# How to specify a C++ pointer to a C function with unknown number of arguments?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, ffi, reinterpret-cast

I'm writing a C library which I would like to be usable from both C and C++. At one moment, it should take a callback from the user with 0-3 arguments, which will be called at some pointer later. Like this (a copy of the code is available as [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/yeputons/b4534e398842bb696921b6b118a6fd3b) too):

```cpp
// app_c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

double f0(void) {
    return 123;
}

double f2(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    cb_arity = 0;
    cb_func = f0;
    printf("%f\n", cb_call());

    cb_arity = 2;
    cb_func = f2;
    printf("%f\n", cb_call());
}
```

I was able to create a pointer to a C function which takes unknown (but still fixed) number of arguments, note it's `void (*cb_func)()`, not `void (*cb_func)(void)`:

```cpp
// lib.h
#ifndef LIB_H_
#define LIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int cb_arity;
extern double (*cb_func)();
double cb_call(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // LIB_H_
```

```cpp
// lib.c
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int cb_arity;
double (*cb_func)();

double cb_call(void) {
    switch (cb_arity) {
        case 0:
            return cb_func();
        case 1:
            return cb_func(10.0);
        case 2:
            return cb_func(10.0, 20.0);
        case 3:
            return cb_func(10.0, 20.0, 30.0);
        default:
            abort();
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs successfully both on my machine and [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NddOroGhY8DXJarN). As far as I understand, no UB is invoked.

Now I would like to make it work in C++ as well. Unfortunately, it looks like I now need `reinterpret_cast` because `()` means "no arguments" in C++, not "unknown number of arguments":

```cpp
// app_cpp.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    cb_arity = 0;
    cb_func = []() { return 123.0; };
    printf("%f\n", cb_call());

    cb_arity = 2;
    cb_func = reinterpret_cast<double(*)()>(static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(
        [](double a, double b) { return a + b; }
    ));
    printf("%f\n", cb_call());
}
```

As far as I understand, no UB is invoked here as well: although I convert function pointer `double(*)(double, double)` to `double(*)(void)` in C++, it's converted back to `double(*)(double, double)` in C code right before calling.

Is there any way to get rid of these ugly casts in C++ code? I've tried specifying type of `cb_func` as `void(*)(...)`, but C++ still won't implicitly convert `double(*)(double, double)` to it.

Comment: Note: such "no arguments" function declarations are "obsolescent feature" since C99 at least, see "6.11.6 Function declarations" in [N1124](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).

Comment: You may wish to reconisider. It's an obsolescent C feature as well. Subject to potential removal https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6

Comment: And as an aside, you can get rid of the `static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>`. Applying `+` to a non-capturing lambda causes a conversion to a function pointer. So `+[](double a, double b) { return a + b; }` will do.

Comment: As an alternative (more usual) way, you could have one callback function with a single argument, a pointer to a struct that contains both the number of values and the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than erase the number of arguments from the callback, you could retain it.

```
// lib.h
#ifndef LIB_H_
#define LIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    int arity;
    union {
        void(*zero)(void);
        void(*one)(double);
        void(*two)(double, double);
        void(*three)(double, double, double);
    }
} cb_type;
extern cb_type cb;

double cb_call(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // LIB_H_
```

```
// lib.c
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

cb_type cb;

double cb_call(void) {
    switch (cb.arity) {
        case 0:
            return cb.zero();
        case 1:
            return cb.one(10.0);
        case 2:
            return cb.two(10.0, 20.0);
        case 3:
            return cb.three(10.0, 20.0, 30.0);
        default:
            abort();
    }
}
```

If you don't expose `cb`, you can't mismatch the arity and union member:

```
// lib.h
#ifndef LIB_H_
#define LIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void register_zero(void(*)(void));
void register_one(void(*)(double));
void register_two(void(*)(double, double));
void register_three(void(*)(double, double, double));

double cb_call(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // LIB_H_
```

Comment: Note that `cb_t` is [reserved by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/767632).

Answer (score 0):

Parameterless function declarations is an obsolescent C feature. I would suggest avoiding it.

Essentially, you're trying to circumvent type checking: you want to store an almost arbitrary function in a `cb_func` variable, and then be able to call it freely without any signs of danger like explicit casts. However, this code is inherently dangerous: if you mess up `cb_arity`, behavior is undefined. Moreover, you can even store `double(*)(int, char*)` to `cb_func` without any warnings, which is never ok in your example.

On a deeper level, your `cb_arity`/`cb_func` looks a lot like a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). The canonical way to implement it in C++ is [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (or something function-specific like [`unique_pseudofunction`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ms0gi5GfL0)). The canonical way to implement it in C is a struct with a "tag" field and an anonymous `union`, like this:

```cpp
struct cb_s {
    int arity;
    union {
        double (*func0)(void);
        double (*func1)(double);
        double (*func2)(double, double);
        double (*func3)(double, double, double);
    };
};

extern struct cb_s cb;
```

Now instead of `cb_func = f0` you write `cb.func0 = f0`, and instead of `cb_func = f2` you write `cb.func2 = f2`. Similary in C++ and all casts from lambdas are now gone. The only remaining sign of danger is the underlying `union`.

You will have to change your code in two places:

1. The library. Here you already know which of `func0`/`func1`/... to call, not a big deal.
2. The user code which wrote to `cb_func`. Now it has to know which union member to write into. Presumably, the same code would also write a compile-time constant `cb_arity`, so not a big deal agian. If `cb_arity` is received from someone else, that someone should then also use tagged union instead of passing `cb_arity` and `cb_func` separately for better type safety.

Sidenote: C++ (as opposed to C) prohibits access to a non-active member of union. This should not affect correctness of the code, because calling a `func0` through a pointer to `func1` is UB by itself.