# Function declaration with typedef as parameter in other file

Tags: c, struct, typedef

There are 3 files:
struct.h:

```
typedef struct weight_sensor_str
{
    uint16_t min_value, max_value;
    uint8_t coeff_percent;
}weight_sensor_t;

extern weight_sensor_t front_sensor;
```

struct.c

```
weight_sensor_t front_sensor = {.min_value = 0, .max_value = 0, .coeff_percent = 0};
```

and other file with function prototype which using this struct:
handle.h

```
#include "struct.h"
void weight_sensor_handle(weight_sensor_t front);
```

building this code gives me error, (even if I include header correctly)

```
unknown type name 'weight_sensor_t' handle.h
```

comment function declaration solved the problem, but I'm getting warning about implicit declaration which is totally normal behaviour:

```
implicit declaration of function 'weight_sensor_handle' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

how to properly declare function with my own typedef struct?

Comment: Either `handle.h` needs to include `struct.h`, or you must include `struct.h` before you include `handle.h`.

Comment: Don't use the `_t` suffix on your name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/140750

Comment: @WilliamPursell forgot to mention, it is included

Comment: It's difficult to see since you have not provided complete code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  My guess is that you are including `struct.h` after `handle.h`.

Comment: The code you've shown us looks fine, so the problem may be in some part that you've left out.  Please make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, it was the problem - inclduing handle.h before struct.h. Thank You for Your help!

Comment: Please create an answer. Consider adapting the question so that the answer becomes obvious to others, or at least makes sense after having been read. Providing a MRE would help a lot with that. Or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the including struct.h file after handle.h