# How do I pass an array of structures to a function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass an array of structs to a function which fills them with data.

When I try to compile the code I am told that there is an error:

```
In function 'main':
    error: expected expression before 'Robot_t'
        loading_Profiles (Robot_t RobotInfo[]);
```

I am not sure what I am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int Robot_Number;
    char Robot_Name[30];
    int Year_Manufacturer;
    float Top_Speed;
    float Mass;
    float Best_Score;
} Robot_t;

void loading_Profiles();

int main()
{
    Robot_t RobotInfo[5];

    loading_Profiles (Robot_t RobotInfo[]);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\n",
               RobotInfo[i].Robot_Number, RobotInfo[i].Robot_Name,
               RobotInfo[i].Year_Manufacturer, RobotInfo[i].Top_Speed, 
               RobotInfo[i].Mass, RobotInfo[i].Best_Score);
    }
    return 0;
}

void loading_Profiles()
{
    int Counter = 0;
    int i;

    Robot_t RobotInfo[5];

    FILE *ROBOTtxt = fopen("Robot.txt", "r");

    if (ROBOTtxt == NULL) {
        perror("an error occured during the loading of the file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        char LineNumber[100] = "";
        fgets(LineNumber, 100, ROBOTtxt);
        sscanf(LineNumber, "%d %s %d %f %f %f",
               &RobotInfo[i].Robot_Number,
               RobotInfo[i].Robot_Name,
               &RobotInfo[i].Year_Manufacturer,
               &RobotInfo[i].Top_Speed,
               &RobotInfo[i].Mass,
               &RobotInfo[i].Best_Score);

        Counter++;

        if (feof(ROBOTtxt)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(ROBOTtxt)) {
        perror("an error has occured");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fclose(ROBOTtxt);
}
```

Comment: Use as prototype: `void loading_Profiles (Robot_t *RobotInfo);` and call as `loading_Profiles (RobotInfo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your program. The obvious one is that your function prototypes do not match:

```
void loading_Profiles()
```

should be

```
void loading_Profiles(Robot_t *robots)
```

in both the declaration and definition.

The array `Robot_t RobotInfo[5]` in `main`, and the `Robot_t RobotInfo[5]` in `loading_Profiles` do not refer to the same array. They are separate arrays, local to each function. You need to pass the array from `main` to the `loading_Profiles` function, which should then modify the array.

Your code also contains various size errors. You are defining an array of `5` elements, and then trying to read and write up to `50` elements. Beyond the mismatch, you need to think about what happens if your file contains less lines than expected.

`Counter` is unused. As are the return values of some functions that can indicate status / errors:

- [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) already partially indicates if it has reached `EOF` by returning `NULL`.
- [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the numbers of conversions that took place, which can be used to make sure a partial set of data wasn't stored.

---

Here is a rewritten example that showcases how to pass arrays around, fill them to a maximum, and utilize the return values of `stdio` functions. Notice how the *type signature* of `load_robot_profiles` matches exactly between the declaration, definition, and invocation of the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int number;
    char name[32];
    int year_manufactured;
    float top_speed;
    float mass;
    float best_score;
} Robot;

size_t load_robot_profiles(Robot *, size_t, const char *);

int main(void) {
    Robot robots[5];
    size_t length = load_robot_profiles(robots, 5, "robots.txt");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Robot *r = &robots[i];

        printf("%d\t%s\t%d\t\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n",
                r->number, r->name, r->year_manufactured,
                r->top_speed, r->mass, r->best_score);
    }
}

size_t load_robot_profiles(Robot *robots, size_t size, const char *fname) {
    size_t i = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(fname, "r");
    char input[128];

    if (!file)
        return 0;

    while (i < size && fgets(input, sizeof input, file)) {
        Robot *r = &robots[i];

        if (6 == sscanf(input, "%d %s %d %f %f %f",
                &r->number, r->name, &r->year_manufactured,
                &r->top_speed, &r->mass, &r->best_score))
            i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return i;
}
```

Also note: Defining a type with a `_t` suffix is ill-advised, as eventually you will brush up against a [conflict with an existing POSIX type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231807/2505965), or other standard.

Comment: yes ok thank you so much, I have had a read through your code you sent and it has helped a lot.

Comment: @smokey Make sure to [accept the answer if it best solves your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your definition and declaration of the function `void loading_Profiles()` don't include any arguments, but you're calling it with an argument: `loading_Profiles (Robot_t RobotInfo[]);`.

You need to change the function to accept `Robot_t RobotInfo[]` as an argument and then modify the `RobotInfo[]` array.

Comment: hey M. Burchell, i declared the prototype, and defined the function to include the argument `Robot_t RobotInfo[]` But i am still returned with the same error

Comment: Did you change the function prototype **above** `main()` as well? Also if you are passing `RobotInfo` to your function as a parameter, then in your function `Robot_t RobotInfo[5];` will shadow your previous array.

Comment: the code i have at the moment in order i.e. prototype `void loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[5]);`, then in `int main(){Robot_t RobotInfo[5]; loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[5]);}` and then i have defined the function with `void loading_Profiles(Robot_t RobotInfo[5])`

Answer (score 0):

The function signature should be like that:

```c
void loading_Profiles(Robot_t* RobotInfo);
```

Also, there is no need to redeclare the `Robot_t RobotInfo[5]` inside your `loading_Profiles` function, since it is already passed by the function call.

Comment: hmmm, i tried this but i am still left with the same error, should i be putting the * in front of all the `Robot_t` expressions?